# Adding an onclick event to a table row

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

I'm trying to add an onclick event to a table row through Javascript.

```
function addRowHandlers() {
    var table = document.getElementById("tableId");
    var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
        row = table.rows[i];
        row.onclick = function(){
                          var cell = this.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
                          var id = cell.innerHTML;
                          alert("id:" + id);
                      };
    }
}
```

This works as expected in Firefox, but in Internet Explorer (IE8) I can't access the table cells. I believe that is somehow related to the fact that "this" in the onclick function is identified as "Window" instead of "Table" (or something like that).

If I could access the the current row I could perform a `getElementById` in the onclick function by I can't find a way to do that. Any suggestions?

Comment: You should start with index 0 (var i = 0;) and not 1.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Something like this.

```
function addRowHandlers() {
  var table = document.getElementById("tableId");
  var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var currentRow = table.rows[i];
    var createClickHandler = function(row) {
      return function() {
        var cell = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
        var id = cell.innerHTML;
        alert("id:" + id);
      };
    };
    currentRow.onclick = createClickHandler(currentRow);
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

Working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/oh16h7cj/).

Comment: Are you sure? It does work. Check the working demo link in my updated answer. Also, in your code, you started index with 1 instead of 0. You will not attach handler to the first row.

Comment: It works but when I saw your solution it was a bit different than it is now... =P I'm really thankful, been banging my head all afternoon!

Comment: Yes, I realized it right after I posted my answer (just like redsquare did) and later corrected it.

Comment: Why is table.rows[i] required? I tried 'var currentRow = rows[i]' and it worked.

Comment: Been looking for this thanks.. EDIT: I get an error `WHte.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null` . I assume that is because I load the rows in dynamically? Therefore no "TR". How do I get around that???

Comment: Great found it... call it post update... Great piece of code!!

Comment: @CromeX can you shop us the snippet of code you have for the error message: 
WHte.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null .
It will be good if you can tell us what web page you are trying to build and the desired result on the page on the web browser. Send a screenshot of the page so we can visualise how we can help you load the 3 rows dynamically. Do let us know if you have resolved the issue or still trying to know how to circumvent that.

Comment: Thanks, it wasn't working for me (iOS Safari), I had to declare var i for it to work

Answer (score 11):

**Simple way is generating code as bellow:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>
  table, td {
      border:1px solid black;
  }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<p>Click on each tr element to alert its index position in the table:</p>
<table>
  <tr onclick="myFunction(this)">
    <td>Click to show rowIndex</td>
  </tr>
  <tr onclick="myFunction(this)">
    <td>Click to show rowIndex</td>
  </tr>
  <tr onclick="myFunction(this)">
    <td>Click to show rowIndex</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
  function myFunction(x) {
      alert("Row index is: " + x.rowIndex);
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8):

I think for IE you will need to use the srcElement property of the [Event object](http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/domevent.shtml). if jQuery is an option for you, you may want to consider using it - as it abstracts most browser differences for you. Example jQuery:

```
$("#tableId tr").click(function() {
   alert($(this).children("td").html());
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a compact and a bit cleaner version of the same pure **Javascript** (*not a jQuery*) solution as discussed above by @redsquare and @SolutionYogi (re: adding `onclick` event handlers to all HTML table rows) that works in all major Web Browsers, including the latest IE11:

```
function addRowHandlers() {
    var rows = document.getElementById("tableId").rows;
    for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        rows[i].onclick = function(){ return function(){
               var id = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
               alert("id:" + id);
        };}(rows[i]);
    }
}
window.onload = addRowHandlers();
```

Working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zsugwbgn/)

*Note*: in order to make it work in IE8 as well, instead of `this` pointer use the explicit identifier like `function(myrow)` as suggested by @redsquare.
Best regards,

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I do this.  I create a table with a thead and tbody tags.
And then add a click event to the tbody element by id.

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("mytbody").click = clickfunc;
    function clickfunc(e) {
        // to find what td element has the data you are looking for
        var tdele = e.target.parentNode.children[x].innerHTML;
        // to find the row
        var trele = e.target.parentNode;
    }
</script>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Header 1</th>
            <th>Header 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="mytbody">
        <tr><td>Data Row</td><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Data Row</td><td>2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Data Row</td><td>3</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Head stuck in jq for too long. This will work.

```
function addRowHandlers() {
    var table = document.getElementById("tableId");
    var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var row = table.rows[i];
        row.onclick = function(myrow){
                          return function() { 
                             var cell = myrow.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
                             var id = cell.innerHTML;
                             alert("id:" + id);
                      };
                  }(row);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would this work? I posted the same example but I think the 'row' inside the onlcick will always refer to the last row. Isn't it? [JavaScript has only function scoping, no block scoping.]

Comment: I know, jQuery makes all these things so easy, when you are left without jQuery, you do all the silly mistakes! :)

Comment: indeed it does! give me an each anyday

Answer (score 1):

I try to figure out how to get a better result with pure JS and i get something this:

**DEMO**: https://jsfiddle.net/f5r3emjt/1/

```
const tbody = document.getElementById("tbody");
let rowSelected;

tbody.onclick = (e) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < e.path.length; ++i) {
    if (e.path[i].tagName == "TR") {
      selectRow(e.path[i]);
      break;
    }
  }
};

function selectRow(r) {
  if (rowSelected !== undefined) rowSelected.style.backgroundColor = "white";

  rowSelected = r;
  rowSelected.style.backgroundColor = "dodgerblue";
}
```

And now you can use the variable **rowSelected** in other function like you want or call another function after set the style

**I like more this implementacion and also compatible with any browser**

```
tbody.onclick = (e) => {
 // we need to get the tr element because we always select the td element
 const tr = e.srcElement.parentNode; 
 tr == "TR" && selectRow( tr );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `this.getElementsByTagName("td")[0])` line to read `row.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];`. That should capture the `row` reference in a closure, and it should work as expected.

Edit: The above is wrong, since row is a global variable -- as others have said, allocate a new variable and then use THAT in the closure.

Answer (score 0):

My table is in another iframe so i modified *SolutionYogi* answer to work with that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = addRowHandlers;
function addRowHandlers() {
    var iframe = document.getElementById('myiframe');
    var innerDoc = (iframe.contentDocument) ? iframe.contentDocument : iframe.contentWindow.document;

    var table = innerDoc.getElementById("mytable");
    var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var currentRow = table.rows[i];
        var createClickHandler = 
            function(row) 
            {
                return function() { 
                                        var cell = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
                                        var id = cell.innerHTML;
                                        alert("id:" + id);
                                 };
            }

        currentRow.onclick = createClickHandler(currentRow);
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to select a table row, so that it can be easily copied to the clipboard and then pasted in Excel. Below is a small adaptation of your solution.

References:

- [Where I took the window.prompt line from (Jarek Milewski)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6055620):

  > The user is presented with the prompt box, where the text to be copied is already selected...
- [For selecting a complete table (Tim Down)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2044793). Very interesting, but I was not able to adapt for a `<tr>` element.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div>
    <table id="tableId" border=1>
      <tbody>
        <tr><td>Item <b>A1</b></td><td>Item <b>B1</b></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Item <b>A2</b></td><td>Item <b>B2</b></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Item <b>A3</b></td><td>Item <b>B3</b></td></tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<script>
function addRowHandlers() {
    var table = document.getElementById("tableId");
    var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var currentRow = table.rows[i];
        var createClickHandler = 
            function(row) 
            {
                return function() { 
                                        var cell = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
                                        var id = cell.innerHTML;

                                        var cell1 = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
                                        var id2 = cell1.innerHTML;
                                        // alert(id + " - " + id2);
                                        window.prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", "<table><tr><td>" + id + "</td><td>" + id2 + "</td></tr></table>")
                                 };
            };

        currentRow.onclick = createClickHandler(currentRow);
    }
}
window.onload = addRowHandlers();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

While most answers are a copy of SolutionYogi's answer, they all miss an important check to see if 'cell' is not null which will return an error if clicking on the headers.
So, here is the answer with the check included:

```
function addRowHandlers() {
  var table = document.getElementById("tableId");
  var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var currentRow = table.rows[i];
    var createClickHandler = function(row) {
      return function() {
        var cell = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
        // check if not null
        if(!cell) return; // no errors! 
        var id = cell.innerHTML;
        alert("id:" + id);
      };
    };
    currentRow.onclick = createClickHandler(currentRow);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
selectRowToInput();
function selectRowToInput(){
var table = document.getElementById("table");
var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++)
{
    var currentRow = table.rows[i];
    currentRow.onclick = function() {

       rows=this.rowIndex;
        console.log(rows);  
    };
}

}
```