# Selecting whole table/text for copying to clipboard

Tags: jquery, clipboard

I have a htlm table with lots of data the user might want to copy to paste into Excel or whatever...

Since it's big I want to help user selecting it, he can then copy & paste himself.

I found this
[Select a complete table with Javascript (to be copied to clipboard)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044616/select-a-complete-table-with-javascript-to-be-copied-to-clipboard)

but it creates a security error (code 1000) in FF, any thoughts? Can this be done more efficiently with jQuery?

Comment: btw I´m not really interested in copying the whole to clipboard (via Google I read it's very complicated, browser peculiar and buggy...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never used it, but there is a [jQuery clipboard plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/clipboard) that could suit your needs.  It sounds like it would copy something to the clipboard, but should work cross-browser.  The code would be something like

```
$.clipboard($('#tableContainer').html());
```

Edit: I just noticed that this solution would require non-IE browsers to have Flash installed, which is inconvenient as best and makes it unusable at worst.  The only way I could think to do this without having the browser access the clip board would be to display a hidden textarea control with the results of this call:

```
$('#tableContainer').html()
```

and then allow the user to select all the text and copy it.  It would work, but not be as elegant as the plugin solution.