# Copy a HTML table via JavaScript without the headers?

Tags: javascript, html, copy, clipboard

Using the JavaScript sample found in this [stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044616/select-a-complete-table-with-javascript-to-be-copied-to-clipboard) you can have a button that automatically selects a table.  This selected table can then be copied to the  clipboard.

My users will be copying this data into an Excel  template  and do not need the header information (`<th></th>`  or `<thead></thead>`).

My table looks something like this:

```
<table class="sortable">
<thead>
  <tr><th>Person</th><th>Monthly pay</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr><td>Bob</td><td>£12,000</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Doug</td><td>£8,500</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Sam</td><td>£9,200</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Nick</td><td>£15,300</td></tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
  <tr><td>TOTAL</td><td>£45,000</td></tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

**How would I go about unselecting the header information?**

**UDPATE1**

The key is to select the tbody (assuming you Do not want tfoot).

```
<input type="image" src="table.png" name="image" onclick="selectElementContents( document.getElementById('theebody') );">
```

Comment: do you need `<tbody>` and `<tfoot>`? Or just `<tbody>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `<table>` has a `<thead>` and `<tbody>`, you could just select the `<tbody>`. However if you have header row(s) as sibling of other rows... [here is a good start](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/range_intro.html) on how to set the range with more control.