# Javascript to export html table to Excel

Tags: javascript, excel

I need to export the html table in my page to an Excel when user clicks 'Export' button. Now, I found a solution here on stack overflow that works in Firefox.

[Export dynamic html table to excel in javascript in firefox browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6955627/export-dynamic-html-table-to-excel-in-javascript-in-firefox-browser)

Now, it doesn't handle special characters like ö,ü,ö which are common in languages we use here so I wanted to ask if anyone knows how I can export them successfully as well without problems?

Here is my code:

```
 function tabletoExcel(table, name) {
    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
          , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
          , base64 = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))); }
          , format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }); };
        if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table);
        var ctx = { worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML };
        window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));

}
```

Comment: With this method you can only export whatever is visible in the page. Are you okay with that approach?

Comment: Yes. That is what I am trying to do. Sometimes, there are names with special characters and they do not get exported correctly. So, I want to know what encoding I should use?

Comment: Its not working in IE..

Comment: Check This 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22317951/export-html-table-data-to-excel-using-javascript-jquery-is-not-working-properl/24081343#24081343

Comment: How can I extend this js, in  order to export multiples tables html in excel?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

If you add:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

in the head of the document it will start working as expected:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var tableToExcel = (function() {
  var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
    , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8"/></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
    , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
    , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
  return function(table, name) {
    if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
    var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
    window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
  }
})()
</script>
```

[Updated Fiddle Here.](http://jsfiddle.net/cmewv/537/)

Comment: @seroth You get this error because you are using IE < 10. http://caniuse.com/#search=btoa

Comment: This is not working for me in IE 11.  When you click on the Export button it just shows that the page is waiting .

Comment: "The file format and extension of download.xls don't match"   this is a problem as end users do not want to see there and click on Yes ....

Comment: How can I export multiples tables with this js?

Comment: Thank you so much. You made my day :)

Comment: @Candide I know the original code is not yours, but do you have any idea of how to get this code to export to xlsx instead of xls?

Comment: @TotZam xlsx is a mix of zip+files, I think it is quite difficult to do it with javascript

Comment: why the file downloaded doesn't come with an extension?

Comment: File is downloaded but when opening the file in MS Excel it shows warning for unmatched header and it's extension.

Comment: hello, how did you came to this solution?how you solve it? @Candide

Comment: @Candide, thanks for your answer. When I download  the file on windows computer, '2.8.5' is shown as date format. Do you know how can I fix this problem?

Comment: @Candide , If there is too much data, I get 'about:blank#blocked' warning in the browser. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 6):

For UTF 8 Conversion and Currency Symbol Export Use this:

```
var tableToExcel = (function() {
  var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
    , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
    , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
    , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
  return function(table, name) {
      if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
      var ctx = { worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML }
    window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
  }
})()
```

Answer (score 1):

ShieldUI's [export to excel](http://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-general/export-to-excel) functionality should already support all special chars.