# HTML table export to Excel (XLS or CSV)

Tags: javascript, html, excel, xlsx

I'm trying to export HTML table content to excel. I saw [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17142427/2517028) which worked but not as I expected it (because ***I can't choose which columns to copy***, and it ***doesn't works with big tables***). 
And another solution to copy by js and manually paste to excel file, which didn't work as well, and I don't really fancy this method.

Shortly what I want is, export customized view of the table, not all columns. to show you an example of what I mean:

**Here is the normal table view:**

[image]

**and Here is how what I want to show in excel:**

[image]

**But because I have hidden fields, the first method didn't work:**

[image]

I would like a client side, cross-browser, workaround/solution,  considering that I have around 2,500 lines in the table.

Comment: I think it would be better if you build the excel sheet in server side , so you could customize it properly.

Comment: will you use any framework like struts,spring etc

Comment: @KanhuBhol Actually, I'm stuck with Classical ASP!!

Comment: @MohamedFarrag, that would be my last resort!

Comment: If you changed your mind, so I recommend to use Office Open https://excelpackage.codeplex.com/ it is a great tool to build excel sheet from scratch.

Comment: As far as I know, you've got to make the export happen on the server, because you've got to set MIME-type headers for your exported Excel document (which Javascript can't do). If you're using ASP, the following links might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/440892/how-to-output-an-excel-xls-file-from-classic-asp http://www.crydust.be/blog/2009/03/02/generate-excel-files-in-asp-classic/ http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/article.php?article=730

Comment: Thank you! Though, I already have my server side excel generation now. I wanted the client side because the table has information from different queries which I don't want to invoke each time someone wants an excel file! by excel I mean either xsl or CSV ...

Comment: Have you tried converting the data to a csv?

Comment: I don't think, it would be a problem to convert the data to CSV, rather than how to save it to the clients' machines?

Answer (score 1):

I made something very similar and use it every day in my office following a tutorial found on the web.
You can use [this template](http://www.fabriziotarizzo.org/documenti/generare-file-excel-da-php/) for PHP:

```
<?
   $filename="sheet.xls";
   header ("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
   header ("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=$filename");
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html lang=it><head>
<title>Titolo</title></head>
<body>
<table border="1">
<?
for ($i=1;$i < 11; $i++)
{
   echo "<tr>";
   for ($j=1; $j<11;$j++)
   {
      $a = $i * $j;
      echo "<td>$a</td>";
   }
   echo "</tr>";
}
?>
</table>
</body></html>
```

You can write something similar with JS, just generate a simple table with HTML tags and be sure to write the correct code in the header.

Answer (score 1):

```
Excel Export Script works on IE7+ , Firefox and Chrome
===========================================================



function fnExcelReport()
    {
             var tab_text="<table border='2px'><tr bgcolor='#87AFC6'>";
             var textRange; var j=0;
          tab = document.getElementById('headerTable'); // id of table


          for(j = 0 ; j < tab.rows.length ; j++) 
          {     
                tab_text=tab_text+tab.rows[j].innerHTML+"</tr>";
                //tab_text=tab_text+"</tr>";
          }

          tab_text=tab_text+"</table>";
          tab_text= tab_text.replace(/<A[^>]*>|<\/A>/g, "");//remove if u want links in your table
          tab_text= tab_text.replace(/<img[^>]*>/gi,""); // remove if u want images in your table
                      tab_text= tab_text.replace(/<input[^>]*>|<\/input>/gi, ""); // reomves input params

               var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
              var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE "); 

                 if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))      // If Internet Explorer
                    {
                           txtArea1.document.open("txt/html","replace");
                           txtArea1.document.write(tab_text);
                           txtArea1.document.close();
                           txtArea1.focus(); 
                            sa=txtArea1.document.execCommand("SaveAs",true,"Say Thanks to Sumit.xls");
                          }  
                  else                 //other browser not tested on IE 11
                      sa = window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text));  


                      return (sa);
                            }

    Just Create a blank iframe

        <iframe id="txtArea1" style="display:none"></iframe>

    Call this function on

        <button id="btnExport" onclick="fnExcelReport();"> EXPORT 
        </button>
```