# Export html table data to Excel using JavaScript / JQuery is not working properly in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, excel, google-chrome

I have a HTML table in velocity template. I want to export the html table data to excel using either java script or jquery, comatibale with all browser. 
I am using below script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ExportToExcel(mytblId){
       var htmltable= document.getElementById('my-table-id');
       var html = htmltable.outerHTML;
       window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(html));
    }
</script>
```

This script works fine in **Mozilla Firefox**,it pops-up with a dialog box of excel and ask for open or save options. But when I tested same script in **Chrome browser it is not working** as expected,when clicked on button there is no pop-up for excel. Data gets downloaded in a file with "file type : file" , no extension like **.xls**
There are no errors in chrome console.

Jsfiddle example :

http://jsfiddle.net/insin/cmewv/

This works fine in mozilla but not in chrome.

Chrome browser Test Case :

First Image:I click on Export to excel button

[image: First Image:I click on Export to excel button]

and result :

[image: Result]

Comment: Test case is for chrome

Comment: Above test case fails if you are using open source product LibreOffice  and Chrome browser. But if you have MS Office installed then code wil work properly.

Answer (score 209, accepted):

Excel export script works on IE7+, Firefox and Chrome.

```js
function fnExcelReport() {
    var tab_text = "<table border='2px'><tr bgcolor='#87AFC6'>";
    var j = 0;
    var tab = document.getElementById('headerTable'); // id of table

    for (j = 0; j < tab.rows.length; j++) {
        tab_text = tab_text + tab.rows[j].innerHTML + "</tr>";
        //tab_text=tab_text+"</tr>";
    }

    tab_text = tab_text + "</table>";
    tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<A[^>]*>|<\/A>/g, "");//remove if u want links in your table
    tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<img[^>]*>/gi, ""); // remove if u want images in your table
    tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<input[^>]*>|<\/input>/gi, ""); // reomves input params

    var msie = window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE ");

    // If Internet Explorer
    if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) {
        txtArea1.document.open("txt/html", "replace");
        txtArea1.document.write(tab_text);
        txtArea1.document.close();
        txtArea1.focus();

        sa = txtArea1.document.execCommand("SaveAs", true, "Say Thanks to Sumit.xls");
    } else {
        // other browser not tested on IE 11
        sa = window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text));
    }

    return sa;
}
```

Just create a blank iframe:

```
<iframe id="txtArea1" style="display:none"></iframe>
```

Call this function on:

```
<button id="btnExport" onclick="fnExcelReport();"> EXPORT </button>
```

Comment: variable txt is not defined

Comment: if not then for what this line is?? var txt = document.getElementById('txtArea1').contentWindow;

Comment: Nothing seems to happen with this solution. Is it still working for you? I know Chrome made an update that may have disabled some of these  file download methods.

Comment: @kyle: What issue you are facing with crome??

Comment: In Chrome, when you click the download button nothing happens at all when using this method. No console errors or anything.

Comment: @Kyle: you cannot simply download in Chrome because now we need to use download API of Chrome.. or else it might be due to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23816005/anchor-tag-download-attribute-not-working-bug-in-chrome-35-0-1916-114 . So developers will have to edit it for Chrome(only Save As functionality).

Comment: Perfect +1 !!! Its working in IE 11, Chrome 35, Firefox 29, Opera 17 But not working in safari 5.1.7 !!! :(

Comment: @Jake: Actually I never tested on safari. Can you tell me what error you are getting?

Comment: Its opening a new tab in browser and showing save or open file , If i click save or open nothing is happening :(

Comment: Is there any way to encode the HTML tags? In my column I have `<b>This is Bold</b>` and instead of that the column showing <b>This is Bold</b>, it should display `This is Bold` in bold text?

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge : You can do that by appending the <br> tab_text </br> or use inner html on its parent node.

Comment: @Jake745 : I never worked for safari but if you need it I'll try.

Comment: @sampopes I want to take the last column of every row and convert the raw HTML into formatter display.

Comment: I tried this: `alert(tab.rows[j].column[0].innerHTML);` but that gave an error.

Comment: how can I change Randome name . I wnat set specefic name .

Comment: @osman: it depends on browser in some cases.. In IE it works but chrome n ff there is a problem..

Comment: Guys, the Chrome browser crashes when I have 18K records to export. Whereas it works fine in IE11. Any suggestions how can I fix this?

Comment: @sidrocks: This depends on browsers internal memory allocation and thus you will have variations based on number of records and length of a record.

Comment: ohk! so seems like completely uncertain... any way I can ascertain before export that if the export is going to cross the browser's internal memory? In this case I can alert the users to filter the data before exporting.
Thanks!

Comment: Cool, the only solution for jquery export of my table that works in Chrome and IE 10   Nice job!

Comment: "The file format and extension of download.xls don't match"    This is not making the manager happy  :/   Any ideas?

Comment: Can anyone please tell me a way to remove a specific column of cells only from being exported to excel, using something like this -> `tab.rows[j].cells[13]`

 ` for(j = 0 ; j < tab.rows.length ; j++) 
    {     
        tab_text=tab_text+tab.rows[j].innerHTML+"</tr>";
    }` ? Any help is reallyappreciated.

Comment: @Disera: You just need to traverse the array one more level down. Use a loop to traverse all cells of rows. Add all cells except the column number of you don't want.

Comment: Works nice, however, images are not inserted properly. Are there any possible solutions?

Comment: Above code works for me on Chrome but not on IE11. Can any one please help?

Comment: @sampopes I am trying to export HTML Table in xls format. But on Safari Browser, its creating unknown file.

Comment: @sampopes Thanks for your useful solution. I have a question based on your answer and I would like to seek your advice please. I have a table, the pagesize is 10 because I have to show 10 rows/records for each page. The table contains 18 rows/records, so the table will have 2 pages, in the button if I click the button to export to excel, it can show rows/records in page 1. However in page 2, if I click the button to export excel, it shows rows/records in page 1.

Comment: @sampopes (cont) At this moment, I guess maybe the browser (Internet Explorer) remembers the content in page 1, so I refresh the browser, click the page 2 of the table and click the button to export the excel, howerver it (the excel) still shows rows/records in page 1.

Comment: @sampopes (cont) What I have tried: I add another iframe `txtArea2` and add code for `txtArea2` inside the function. I run the program, the result is the same. Do you have idea about how to export table data based on table pages? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Learner: At the time of exporting data your only one page will be loaded if you are using ajax calls/ websockets to get the data. So you may have to use something like cookies or local db to store data.

Comment: Confirm @sidrocks words about size limitation. Chrome exports only 3000 rows instead of 10000 in table, whilst IE exports fine.

Comment: @sampopes - I cannot change the name of file. In Chrome the file is downloaded as `download.xls` and in Firefox it is downloaded as `some_random_generated_name.xls`. Surprisingly, it works fine in IE10+

Comment: @AakashGoplani : Its a chrome & firefox policy for local file store. It was not a problem for me and other users so never tried to patch up something to fix this.

Comment: Is it possible to export to multisheet book via this approach?

Comment: @Suncatcher No. You can try other heavy built JS or Java libraries for that.

Comment: What about Edge?

Comment: works well, supports unicode languages (arabic), perfect, no iframe needed

Comment: Please be aware that using `txtArea1.contentDocument` or `txtArea1.contentWindow.document` instead of `txtArea1.document` might save you some troubles

Comment: Any idea how to convert multiple html tables to multiple sheets in same excel?

Comment: @HimalayaGarg: Multiple sheets would need xlsx format for which you will have to something which is bigger, may be a library or service. Try https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/simple.html

Comment: is it possible ti change the file name from "download.xls" to something else ?

Comment: Its something which is browserDependant as our js is run by browser. In case of xhr request the file name is retained but otherwise not.

Comment: i know this is old.. but for so many upvotes, is it just me or does that generate invalid Html (only one <tr>.. ever.. but potentially so many </trs> ?

Comment: I'm not able to do EXCEL operations with this sheet. eg: Autosum. Do we have any other way to do this..?

Comment: export name is always `download.xls`

Comment: I have implemented this function however when using Chrome Version 79.0.3945.130 I keep getting a new tab opening with about:blank#blocked. I have adjusted the privacy settings to allow notifications, flash, automatic downloads, and pop-ups and redirects however no success. Any suggessions on rectifying this will be appreciated.

Comment: code works like magic!! but I have an issue. When I use datatable, it only displays first 10 data entries as default. How can I get all datatable entries? please help

Comment: How can I deploy this with multiple sheets within the same excel file?

Comment: excellent, but if we can customize the name of the file in firefox and chrome it will be great

Comment: What can we do in case of pagination?

Comment: Great..! I uswe this function with Query Button click event and it works!

Comment: I want to write bootstrap class inside tab_text for custom header with data. How can I write?

Answer (score 47):

Datatable plugin solves the purpose best and allows us to export the HTML table data into Excel , PDF , TEXT. easily configurable.

Please find the complete example in below datatable reference link :

https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/simple.html

(screenshot from datatable reference site)
[image]

Comment: OMG! This is an awesome plugin!... and has several plugins embedded!!
Export, Sort, Reorder, Print Preview, etc... Solved all my data showing needs in just 1 shot!

Comment: Can I apply styles to my excel using this plugin?

Comment: @Addy this is a DataTables only solution though, right?

Comment: The export button will remove each page row count drop down, if you want to keep both things ? please check https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/pageLength.html to resolve it.

Comment: The plugin is great. Is there a way to just extract the relevant code to export the data and highlight here? That'd be a great help. Thanks in advance

Comment: this is good! but i have a problem with this plugin is not support multiple <tr> in <thead> is there any solution, please let me know. thanks!

Answer (score 45):

This could help

```js
function exportToExcel() {
    const uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,';
    const template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>';

    const base64 = (s) => window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)));

    const format = function (template, context) {
        return template.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, (m, p) => context[p])
    };

    const html = document.getElementById('tableId').innerHTML;
    const ctx = {
        worksheet: 'Worksheet',
        table: html,
    };

    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = "export.xls";
    link.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
    link.click();
}
```

Comment: what if I only want to export columns which are visible in the html table??

Comment: Hi there, i'm not able to do any EXCEL operations with the sheet, eg: Autosum.  Is that because of data format of this EXCEL sheet or any other issues.. I need help to do some operations.

Answer (score 27):

You can use **tableToExcel.js** to export table in excel file.

This works in a following way :

1). **Include this CDN in your project/file**

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/linways/table-to-excel@v1.0.4/dist/tableToExcel.js"></script>
```

2). **Either Using JavaScript:**

```
<button id="btnExport" onclick="exportReportToExcel(this)">EXPORT REPORT</button>

function exportReportToExcel() {
  let table = document.getElementsByTagName("table"); // you can use document.getElementById('tableId') as well by providing id to the table tag
  TableToExcel.convert(table[0], { // html code may contain multiple tables so here we are refering to 1st table tag
    name: `export.xlsx`, // fileName you could use any name
    sheet: {
      name: 'Sheet 1' // sheetName
    }
  });
}
```

3). **Or by Using Jquery**

```
<button id="btnExport">EXPORT REPORT</button>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnExport").click(function() {
        let table = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
        TableToExcel.convert(table[0], { // html code may contain multiple tables so here we are refering to 1st table tag
           name: `export.xlsx`, // fileName you could use any name
           sheet: {
              name: 'Sheet 1' // sheetName
           }
        });
    });
});
```

You may refer to this github link for any other information

https://github.com/linways/table-to-excel/tree/master

or for referring the live example visit the following link

https://codepen.io/rohithb/pen/YdjVbb

Hope this will help someone :-)

Comment: This is one of the easy and best way , thanks @aman

Comment: is there any way that we can ignore some of the columns before exporting ?

Comment: @JeganBaskaran yes, this library comes with built-in attribute "<tr data-exclude="true"></tr>". I know it is late but it might help someone :)

Answer (score 15):

Instead of using `window.open` you can use a link with the `onclick` event.
And you can put the html table into the uri and set the file name to be downloaded.

Live demo :

```js
function exportF(elem) {
  var table = document.getElementById("table");
  var html = table.outerHTML;
  var url = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + escape(html); // Set your html table into url 
  elem.setAttribute("href", url);
  elem.setAttribute("download", "export.xls"); // Choose the file name
  return false;
}
```

```html
<table id="table" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      Foo
    </td>
    <td>
      Bar
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<a id="downloadLink" onclick="exportF(this)">Export to excel</a>
```

Comment: how can i setting the table border , td width etc in function ?

Answer (score 14):

[TableExport](https://tableexport.travismclarke.com) - The simple, easy-to-implement library to export HTML tables to xlsx, xls, csv, and txt files.

To use this library, simple call the [`TableExport`](https://tableexport.travismclarke.com) constructor:

```
new TableExport(document.getElementsByTagName("table"));

// OR simply

TableExport(document.getElementsByTagName("table"));

// OR using jQuery

$("table").tableExport();
```

Additional properties can be passed-in to customize the look and feel of your tables, buttons, and exported data. [See here more info](https://tableexport.travismclarke.com)

Comment: Does it support PhantomJs? How to report bugs?

Answer (score 9):

http://wsnippets.com/export-html-table-data-excel-sheet-using-jquery/
try this link it might solve your problem

[image]

Comment: Uchit,thank you for your answer.But I have already tried this example.As I have mentioned I question it it work fine in Mozilla but not in Chorme.Can please try this example in Chrome browser ?

Comment: I have tried Your code on jsfiddle and i m getting positive result. It's working fine even in chorme. You can see in the above image that download was sucessfull

Comment: Uchit,thank you.Yes the code is working. Problem is I was using Libre Office,so in Chrome export to excel was not working fine (ref screen shot in m question). But in MS office it working,as you have mentioned. Thank you for providing a jQuery code for this.

Comment: This function is not exporting the values of fields having drop downs..and timestamps

Comment: it doesn't work with multiples tables html, only with one table. How can I do this with multiples tables??????

Comment: I wasn't able to open mentioned link?

Answer (score 8):

**Simplest way using Jquery**

Just add this after head Tag:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/linways/table-to-excel@v1.0.4/dist/tableToExcel.js"></script>
```

Then add Jquery script inside Body Tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#exportBtn1").click(function(){
        TableToExcel.convert(document.getElementById("tab1"), {
            name: "Traceability.xlsx",
            sheet: {
            name: "Sheet1"
            }
          });
        });
  });
</script>
```

Then add HTML button:

```
<button id="exportBtn1">Export To Excel</button><br><br>
```

Note: `"exportBtn1"` will be button ID  and
"tab1" will be table ID

Answer (score 7):

My merge of these examples:

https://www.codexworld.com/export-html-table-data-to-excel-using-javascript
https://bl.ocks.org/Flyer53/1de5a78de9c89850999c

```
function exportTableToExcel(tableId, filename) {
    let dataType = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
    let extension = '.xls';

    let base64 = function(s) {
        return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)))
    };

    let template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>';
    let render = function(template, content) {
        return template.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return content[p]; });
    };

    let tableElement = document.getElementById(tableId);

    let tableExcel = render(template, {
        worksheet: filename,
        table: tableElement.innerHTML
    });

    filename = filename + extension;

    if (navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob)
    {
        let blob = new Blob(
            [ '\ufeff', tableExcel ],
            { type: dataType }
        );

        navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, filename);
    } else {
        let downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

        document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

        downloadLink.href = 'data:' + dataType + ';base64,' + base64(tableExcel);

        downloadLink.download = filename;

        downloadLink.click();
    }
}
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: base64 is not defined

Answer (score 4):

You can use a library like ShieldUI to do that.

It supports exporting to both XML and XLSX widely-used Excel formats.

More details here: http://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-general/export-to-excel

Answer (score 4):

Regarding to sampopes answer from Jun 6 '14 at 11:59:

I have insert a css style with font-size of 20px to display the excel data greater. In sampopes code the leading `<tr>` tags are missing, so i first output the headline and than the other tables lines within a loop.

```
function fnExcelReport()
{
    var tab_text = '<table border="1px" style="font-size:20px" ">';
    var textRange; 
    var j = 0;
    var tab = document.getElementById('DataTableId'); // id of table
    var lines = tab.rows.length;

    // the first headline of the table
    if (lines > 0) {
        tab_text = tab_text + '<tr bgcolor="#DFDFDF">' + tab.rows[0].innerHTML + '</tr>';
    }

    // table data lines, loop starting from 1
    for (j = 1 ; j < lines; j++) {     
        tab_text = tab_text + "<tr>" + tab.rows[j].innerHTML + "</tr>";
    }

    tab_text = tab_text + "</table>";
    tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<A[^>]*>|<\/A>/g, "");             //remove if u want links in your table
    tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<img[^>]*>/gi,"");                 // remove if u want images in your table
    tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<input[^>]*>|<\/input>/gi, "");    // reomves input params
    // console.log(tab_text); // aktivate so see the result (press F12 in browser)

    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE "); 

     // if Internet Explorer
    if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) {
        txtArea1.document.open("txt/html","replace");
        txtArea1.document.write(tab_text);
        txtArea1.document.close();
        txtArea1.focus(); 
        sa = txtArea1.document.execCommand("SaveAs", true, "DataTableExport.xls");
    }  
    else // other browser not tested on IE 11
        sa = window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text));  

    return (sa);
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to remove specific column from being exported to excel. For example, i want to avoid `tab.rows[j].cells[13] `, your help is really appreciated

Comment: Very nice answer, for a very simple table I would just keep the last line: ```window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text));``` the enconding is very important.

Answer (score 4):

```js
 function exportToExcel() {
        var tab_text = "<tr bgcolor='#87AFC6'>";
        var textRange; var j = 0, rows = '';
        tab = document.getElementById('student-detail');
        tab_text = tab_text + tab.rows[0].innerHTML + "</tr>";
        var tableData = $('#student-detail').DataTable().rows().data();
        for (var i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++) {
            rows += '<tr>'
                + '<td>' + tableData[i].value1 + '</td>'
                + '<td>' + tableData[i].value2 + '</td>'
                + '<td>' + tableData[i].value3 + '</td>'
                + '<td>' + tableData[i].value4 + '</td>'
                + '<td>' + tableData[i].value5 + '</td>'
                + '<td>' + tableData[i].value6 + '</td>'
                + '<td>' + tableData[i].value7 + '</td>'
                + '<td>' +  tableData[i].value8 + '</td>'
                + '<td>' + tableData[i].value9 + '</td>'
                + '<td>' + tableData[i].value10 + '</td>'
                + '</tr>';
        }
        tab_text += rows;
        var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
            template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table border="2px">{table}</table></body></html>',
            base64 = function (s) {
                return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)))
            },
            format = function (s, c) {
                return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) {
                    return c[p];
                })
            }

        var ctx = {
            worksheet: "Sheet 1" || 'Worksheet',
            table: tab_text
        }
        document.getElementById("dlink").href = data_type + base64(format(template, ctx));
        document.getElementById("dlink").download = "StudentDetails.xls";
        document.getElementById("dlink").traget = "_blank";
        document.getElementById("dlink").click();
    }
```

Here Value 1 to 10 are column names that you are getting

Answer (score 3):

Below code will work on latest **Chrome , Edge , Firefox** , not require 3rd party library.

**HTML**

```
<button onclick="download_table_as_csv('MyTableID_Value');">Export as CSV</button>
```

**Jscript**

```
function download_table_as_csv(table_id, separator = ',') {
// Select rows from table_id
var rows = document.querySelectorAll('table#' + table_id + ' tr');
// Construct csv
var csv = [];
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var row = [], cols = rows[i].querySelectorAll('td, th');
    for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
        // Clean innertext to remove multiple spaces and jumpline (break csv)
        var data = cols[j].innerText.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, '').replace(/(\s\s)/gm, ' ')
        // Escape double-quote with double-double-quote (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17808511/properly-escape-a-double-quote-in-csv)
        data = data.replace(/"/g, '""');
        // Push escaped string
        row.push('"' + data + '"');
    }
    csv.push(row.join(separator));
}
var csv_string = csv.join('\n');
// Download it
var filename = 'export_' + table_id + '_' + new Date().toLocaleDateString() + '.csv';
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.style.display = 'none';
link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
link.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv_string));
link.setAttribute('download', filename);
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
document.body.removeChild(link);}
```

Answer (score 1):

My version of @sampopes answer

```
function exportToExcel(that, id, hasHeader, removeLinks, removeImages, removeInputParams) {
if (that == null || typeof that === 'undefined') {
    console.log('Sender is required');
    return false;
}

if (!(that instanceof HTMLAnchorElement)) {
    console.log('Sender must be an anchor element');
    return false;
}

if (id == null || typeof id === 'undefined') {
    console.log('Table id is required');
    return false;
}
if (hasHeader == null || typeof hasHeader === 'undefined') {
    hasHeader = true;
}
if (removeLinks == null || typeof removeLinks === 'undefined') {
    removeLinks = true;
}
if (removeImages == null || typeof removeImages === 'undefined') {
    removeImages = false;
}
if (removeInputParams == null || typeof removeInputParams === 'undefined') {
    removeInputParams = true;
}

var tab_text = "<table border='2px'>";
var textRange;

tab = $(id).get(0);

if (tab == null || typeof tab === 'undefined') {
    console.log('Table not found');
    return;
}

var j = 0;

if (hasHeader && tab.rows.length > 0) {
    var row = tab.rows[0];
    tab_text += "<tr bgcolor='#87AFC6'>";
    for (var l = 0; l < row.cells.length; l++) {
        if ($(tab.rows[0].cells[l]).is(':visible')) {//export visible cols only
            tab_text += "<td>" + row.cells[l].innerHTML + "</td>";
        }
    }
    tab_text += "</tr>";
    j++;
}

for (; j < tab.rows.length; j++) {
    var row = tab.rows[j];
    tab_text += "<tr>";
    for (var l = 0; l < row.cells.length; l++) {
        if ($(tab.rows[j].cells[l]).is(':visible')) {//export visible cols only
            tab_text += "<td>" + row.cells[l].innerHTML + "</td>";
        }
    }
    tab_text += "</tr>";
}

tab_text = tab_text + "</table>";
if (removeLinks)
    tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<A[^>]*>|<\/A>/g, "");
if (removeImages)
    tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<img[^>]*>/gi, ""); 
if (removeInputParams)
    tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<input[^>]*>|<\/input>/gi, "");

var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))      // If Internet Explorer
{
    myIframe.document.open("txt/html", "replace");
    myIframe.document.write(tab_text);
    myIframe.document.close();
    myIframe.focus();
    sa = myIframe.document.execCommand("SaveAs", true, document.title + ".xls");
    return true;
}
else {
    //other browser tested on IE 11
    var result = "data:application/vnd.ms-excel," + encodeURIComponent(tab_text);
    that.href = result;
    that.download = document.title + ".xls";
    return true;
}
}
```

Requires an iframe

```
<iframe id="myIframe" style="opacity: 0; width: 100%; height: 0px;" seamless="seamless"></iframe>
```

Usage

```
$("#btnExportToExcel").click(function () {
    exportToExcel(this, '#mytable');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Very Easy Code
Follow this instruction
Create excel.php file in your localhost root directory and copy and past this code.
Like this
http://localhost/excel.php?fileName=excelfile&link=1
<!-- http://localhost/excel.php?fileName=excelfile&link=2 -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Export excel file from html table</title>
</head>
<body style="display:
<?php 
if( $_REQUEST['link'] == 1 ){
    echo 'none';
}
?>;
">

<!-- --------Optional-------- -->
Excel <input type="radio" value="1" name="exportFile">
Others <input type="radio" value="2" name="exportFile">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Download</button>
<br>
<br>
<!-- --------/Optional-------- -->

<table width="100%" id="tblData">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Student Name</th>
            <th>Group</th>
            <th>Roll No.</th>
            <th>Class</th>
            <th>Contact No</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Bulbul Sarker</td>
            <td>Science</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Nine</td>
            <td>01724....</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Karim</td>
            <td>Science</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Nine</td>
            <td>0172444...</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>

<style>
    table#tblData{
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    #tblData th,
    #tblData td{
        border:1px solid #CCC;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

    /*--------Optional--------*/
    function myFunction() {
        let val = document.querySelector('input[name="exportFile"]:checked').value;     
        if(val == 1)
        {
            this.exportTableToExcel();
        }
    }
    /*--------/Optional--------*/

    function exportTableToExcel(){
        let filename2 = "<?php echo $_REQUEST['fileName']; ?>";
        let tableId = 'tblData';

        var downloadLink;
        var dataType = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
        var tableSelect = document.getElementById(tableId);
        var tableHTML = tableSelect.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');

            // Specify file name
            let filename = filename2?filename2+'.xls':'excel_data.xls';

            // Create download link element
            downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

            document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

            if(navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob){
                var blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', tableHTML], {
                    type: dataType
                });
                navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob( blob, filename);
            }else{
            // Create a link to the file
            downloadLink.href = 'data:' + dataType + ', ' + tableHTML;

            // Setting the file name
            downloadLink.download = filename;

            //triggering the function
            downloadLink.click();
        }       
    }
</script>

<?php
if( $_REQUEST['link'] == 1 ){       
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    exportTableToExcel();
    </script>'; 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Html**

```
<a onclick="download_to_excel()">Download</a> 

    
 <table id="tableId">
          <thead>
              <tr>
              <th>No</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Address</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="3">Data Not Found</td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function download_to_excel()
{ 

var tab_text="<table><tr>";
var textRange = ''; 
var j=0;
var tab = document.getElementById('tableId'); // id of table

for(j = 0 ; j < tab.rows.length ; j++) 
{     
    tab_text += tab.rows[j].innerHTML+"</tr>";
}

tab_text +="</table>";

var a = document.createElement('a');
var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel';
a.href = data_type + ', ' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text);
//setting the file name
a.download = 'file_name.xls';
//triggering the function
a.click();
//just in case, prevent default behaviour
e.preventDefault();

}
```