# how to export html table and append as a sheet in existing excel using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to export many html table as a single excel file and each html table in a new sheet.

how to export html table  and append as a sheet in existing excel using javascript or jquery 
and how to rename the sheet ?

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22317951/export-html-table-data-to-excel-using-javascript-jquery-is-not-working-properl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally this kind of job can be easily done by VB or C#.

But if you really need to solve this by javascript, you can try this js lib.

http://excelbuilderjs.com/

[Here](http://excelbuilderjs.com/cookbook/addingDataToAWorksheet.html) is the documentation on how to add data to worksheet.

Comment: Ok I will try this. Whether VB code can be integrated with PHP ? If so how it can be done in VB ? Kindly help me

Comment: If you are using PHP, you can use PHP's csv function.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

OR PHPExcel.

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel