# How to append a HTML table to an existing Excel file ideally with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, excel, append

Ok, so I have a setup where things get tested and the data is sent to a website in a HTML table in a local network. Now I want to export the table data to an already existing Excel file and create a new sheet every run with the use of a button on the site. Ideally in JavaScript or another HTML script language. I have already found many "solutions" where the data is just downloaded but that's not what I want. The only thing I found that goes in the same direction is this thread: [how to export html table and append as a sheet in existing excel using javascript or jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27955417/how-to-export-html-table-and-append-as-a-sheet-in-existing-excel-using-javascrip)
but the lib is no longer maintained and the website is offline thus providing no documentation.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the SheetJS Community Edition library to create a [working codepen](https://codepen.io/lucasroquilly/pen/LYQrepQ) on your problem.

The code :

- Uses HTML table data to create a Sheet
- Downloads original XLS file
- Appends new sheet to original XLS file
- Launchs download of the new file

Below snippet, please test on codepen because the XLS file download does not work in the snippet frame.

```js
(async() => {
  // GET DATA TO APPEND FROM HTML TABLE
  var data_to_append = XLSX.utils.table_to_book(document.getElementById("test_table"));
  // GET SHEET "Sheet1" FROM DATA TO APPEND
  const newSheet = data_to_append.Sheets["Sheet1"];
  // GET ORIGINAL XLS FILE
  const url = "https://www.lucasroquilly.com/stack_overflow_samples/workbook.xls";
  const data = await (await fetch(url)).arrayBuffer();
  /* CREATE WORKBOOK FROM ORIGINAL XLS FILE DATA */
  const workbook = XLSX.read(data);
  // APPEND SHEET TO WORKBOOK UNDER NAME "Appended Sheet"
  XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, newSheet, "Appended Sheet", true);
  //ATTEMPT TO LAUNCH DOWNLOAD OF FILE
  XLSX.writeFile(workbook, 'workbook.xls');
})();
```

```css
.tftable {font-size:12px;color:#333333;width:100%;border-width: 1px;border-color: #729ea5;border-collapse: collapse;}
.tftable th {font-size:12px;background-color:#acc8cc;border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #729ea5;text-align:left;}
.tftable tr {background-color:#d4e3e5;}
.tftable td {font-size:12px;border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #729ea5;}
.tftable tr:hover {background-color:#ffffff;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.sheetjs.com/xlsx-0.18.8/package/dist/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
<table id="test_table" class="tftable" border="1">
<tr><th>Header 1</th><th>Header 2</th><th>Header 3</th><th>Header 4</th><th>Header 5</th></tr>
<tr><td>NEW Row:1 Cell:1</td><td>NEW Row:1 Cell:2</td><td>NEW Row:1 Cell:3</td><td>NEW Row:1 Cell:4</td><td>Row:1 Cell:5</td></tr>
<tr><td>NEW Row:2 Cell:1</td><td>NEW Row:2 Cell:2</td><td>NEW Row:2 Cell:3</td><td>NEW Row:2 Cell:4</td><td>NEW Row:2 Cell:5</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but if I open the code in codepen it downloads a workbook.xls file and next to it is written: "Error - network error" and the file can't be opened. If I copy and paste https://www.lucasroquilly.com/stack_overflow_samples/workbook.xls directly in the browser the download works and the file can be opened. When I paste all the code in a HTML file only the table is shown and nothing else happens.

Comment: What do you mean by "next to it" ? Where is it written network error ? Codepen is working on both my computers so im not sure what is wrong.

Comment: Well, it is working now, that is really weird.

Comment: Maybe your browser settings prevented downloads from codepen.io because you refreshed the page a few times triggering multiple downloads at the same time, happened to me before. Please upvote and mark answer as accepted if that was useful 

Comment: I would love to do that but I don't have enough reputation for that.