# Table2excel plugin does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, jquery-plugins

I am working on a dashboard app and I would like to implement "download table as .xls" feature.

On this link you can see how the table looks like
[dashboard](http://pasteboard.co/p82eqze.png)

I have found a [library](https://github.com/rainabba/jquery-table2excel) which also includes the tutorial that explains the set up. As you can see in the code below I have done more or less everything like it was explained. However it does not work and for some reason the table will not be exported.

As you can see, I have included `jquery.table2excel.js` in the resources together with all other resources which are used for this page. I have also checked if the `.js` file is available after the page is loaded and it also looks good.

I have also tried this

```
    $(function () {
            document.getElementById('btnExport').addEventListener("click", function () {
                document.getElementById('myTable').table2excel({
                    exclude: ".noExl",
                    name: "Excel Document Name",
                    filename: "myFileName"
                });
            });
        });
```

but it also does not look well and when I execute the function I get this message in the debugg console

`TypeError: document.getElementById(...).table2excel is not a function`

This is how my `index.jsp` looks like at the moment

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>KPI Admin</title>

    <link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/addition.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />

    <script src="<c:url value="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js" />"></script>
    <script src="<c:url value="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js" />"></script>
    <script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/bootstrap.js" />"></script>
    <script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/addition.js" />"></script>
    <script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery.table2excel.js" />"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            document.getElementById('btnExport').addEventListener("click", function () {
                $(".table2excel").table2excel({
                    exclude: ".noExl",
                    name: "Excel Document Name",
                    filename: "myFileName"
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <!-- /.nav -->
</nav>

<div class="container">
    <div class="starter-template">

        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <!-- /.tabs -->
        </ul>

        <!-- Tab panes -->
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="A">
                <form:form action="/KPIAdmin/kpis" method="get">


                    <div class="row form-inline">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="date">Date</label>
                            <input id="startDatePicker" type="text" class="form-control" name="date" value="${date}" >
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>             
                    </div>
                    <br>

                    <div class="table-responsive">            
                        <table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered table2excel">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Name</td>
                                    <td>Last import</td>
                                    <td>Last value</td>
                                    <td colspan="4">Values</td>
                                    <td colspan="3">Targets</td>
                                    <td colspan="3">Score</td>
                                    <td>Action</td>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td class="text-center" style="font-weight: 700;">DTD</td>
                                <td class="text-center" style="font-weight: 700;">WTD</td>
                                <td class="text-center" style="font-weight: 700;">MTD</td>
                                <td class="text-center" style="font-weight: 700;">YTD</td>
                                <td class="text-center" style="font-weight: 700;">0</td>
                                <td class="text-center" style="font-weight: 700;">100</td>
                                <td class="text-center" style="font-weight: 700;">150</td>
                                <td class="text-center" style="font-weight: 700;">WTD</td>
                                <td class="text-center" style="font-weight: 700;">MTD</td>
                                <td class="text-center" style="font-weight: 700;">YTD</td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <c:forEach var="row" items="${rows}" varStatus="loop">
                                <!-- /.loop that creates the table -->
                            </c:forEach>
                            <tr>
                                <!-- /. last row mean -->
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>

                </form:form>
                <button id="btnExport" class="btn btn-default">Export as .xls</button>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="B"> <!-- Content inside tab B --> </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="C"> <!-- Content inside tab C --> </div>
        </div>

    </div>    
</div><!-- /.container -->
```

I am realy not sure what could cause this problem or do I have an error in the jQuery syntax. It could be also that the lib is not inportet correctly within `.jsp` page but this is the way which was working for me in the past. I guess that I am using right `jQuery` version since `jQuery datePicker` works fine.

If you are able to see what could case this issue, please help me to fix it. If you have any better idea how to export a table as an excel file please suggest.

Thx in advance.

**Edit 1:**

I have changed the function and it looks like the code I have posted below. If I execute `console.log("exporting...");` before or after `$(".table2excel").table2excel({ ... });` "exporing..." will be printed out in the console. Obviously that excludes jQuery as a potential cause of the problem.

```
<script>
        $(function () {
            $('#btnExport').click(function () {
                console.log("exporting...");
                $(".table2excel").table2excel({
                    exclude: ".noExl",
                    name: "Excel Document Name",
                    filename: "myFileName"
                });    
            });
        });
    </script>
```

**Edit 2:**

Since I was not able to fix this, I have tried to try something new. I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22317951/export-html-table-data-to-excel-using-javascript-jquery-is-not-working-properl) solutions and it works but still not as I would really like to, so I hope that you can help me to improve it.

My table looks like this
[image: Table in html]

and this is what I get as a result
[image: Table in excel]

First of all it really looks strange without excel grid, do you have an Idea why the file is exported without it and how can I add it?

Second I would like to remove the column after YTD where the additional infos are presented. Is it somehow possible to adjust the `tab_text.replace(...)` below in order to achive this

in html it looks like this

```
</td><td width='20px'>
    <a class='infobox' href=''> 
        <img src='img/info.jpg' alt='info' width='18' height='18'>
        <span> Service Engineer: ... <br>
               Datasource: ...
        </span>
    </a>
</tr>
```

JavaScript function looks like this

```
function exportExcelReport(tblId) {
    var tab_text = "<table border='2px'><tr>";
    var table = document.getElementById(tblId);

    var style;
    for (var j = 0; j < table.rows.length; j++) {
        style = table.rows[j].className.split(" ");
        if (style.length < 2)
        tab_text = tab_text + table.rows[j].innerHTML + "</tr>";
    }

    tab_text = tab_text + "</table>";
    tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<a[^>]*>|<\/a>/g, "");
    tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<img[^>]*>/gi, "");
    tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<input[^>]*>|<\/input>/gi, "");

    return window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text));
}
```

Thx!

Answer (score 1):

add this before return

```
tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<a class='infobox'[\s\S]*?<\/a>/gi, "");
```

you can play around the string in the replace (before the comma) on this site: [regexr.com](http://regexr.com/)

more info on multiline match [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16119722/2866644)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the script reference for your plug-in is after the jQuery one, and also check both are included before your js code.

Comment: Please try to show a code with your answer to make it more readable.

Comment: $(function(){
        $("body").on("click","button",function(){
            exportExcel();
        });
        function exportExcel(){
            $(".table").table2excel({
                exclude: ".noExl",
                name: "Excel Document Name",
                filename: "myFileName",
                fileext: ".xls",
                exclude_img: true,
                exclude_links: true,
                exclude_inputs: true
            });
        }
    })

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zh-cn">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>人数统计</title>

        <style type="text/css">
            td,
            th {
                vertical-align: middle !important;
                text-align: center;
            }

            .bg_yellow{
                background-color: #fff45c;
            }

            .bg_green {
                background-color: #80c269;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
<button>导出按钮</button>
    <table class="table table-bordered" style="width: 95%; margin: 20px auto;">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col" rowspan="2">a</th>
                                    <th scope="col" colspan="16">b</th>
                                    <th scope="col" colspan="16">c</th>
                                    <th scope="col" colspan="4">d</th>
                                    <th scope="col" rowspan="2">e</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col">f</th>
                                    <th scope="col">g</th>
                                    <th scope="col">h</th>
                                    <th scope="col" class="bg_green">i</th>
                                    <th scope="col">j</th>
                                    <th scope="col">k</th>
                                    <th scope="col">l</th>
                                    <th scope="col">m</th>
                                    <th scope="col">n</th>
                                    <th scope="col">o</th>
                                    <th scope="col" class="bg_green">p</th>
                                    <th scope="col">q</th>
                                    <th scope="col">l</th>
                                    <th scope="col">r</th>
                                    <th scope="col" class="bg_green">s</th>
                                    <th scope="col" class="bg_yellow">t</th>
                                    <th scope="col">u</th>
                                    <th scope="col">v</th>
                                    <th scope="col">w</th>
                                    <th scope="col" class="bg_green">x</th>
                                    <th scope="col">1</th>
                                    <th scope="col">2</th>
                                    <th scope="col">3</th>
                                    <th scope="col">4</th>
                                    <th scope="col">5</th>
                                    <th scope="col">6</th>
                                    <th scope="col" class="bg_green">z</th>
                                    <th scope="col">7</th>
                                    <th scope="col">8</th>
                                    <th scope="col">9</th>
                                    <th scope="col" class="bg_green">y</th>
                                    <th scope="col" class="bg_yellow">z</th>
                                     <th scope="col">7</th>
                                    <th scope="col">8</th>
                                    <th scope="col">9</th>
                                    <th scope="col" class="bg_yellow">z</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>

                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td class="bg_green">0</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td class="bg_green">0</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td class="bg_green">0</td>
                                    <td class="bg_yellow03">0</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td class="bg_green">0</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td class="bg_green">0</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td class="bg_green">0</td>
                                    <td class="bg_yellow03">0</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td class="bg_yellow03">0</td>
                                    <td>0</td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td class="bg_green">0</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td class="bg_green">0</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td class="bg_green">0</td>
                                    <td class="bg_yellow03">0</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td class="bg_green">0</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td class="bg_green">0</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td class="bg_green">0</td>
                                    <td class="bg_yellow03">0</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td class="bg_yellow03">0</td>
                                    <td>0</td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td class="bg_green">0</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td class="bg_green">0</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td class="bg_green">0</td>
                                    <td class="bg_yellow">0</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td class="bg_green">0</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td class="bg_green">0</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td class="bg_green">0</td>
                                    <td class="bg_yellow">0</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td class="bg_yellow">0</td>
                                    <td>0</td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td class="bg_green">0</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td class="bg_green">0</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td class="bg_green">0</td>
                                    <td class="bg_yellow">0</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td class="bg_green">0</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td class="bg_green">0</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td class="bg_green">0</td>
                                    <td class="bg_yellow">0</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td class="bg_yellow">0</td>
                                    <td>0</td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td class="bg_green">0</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td class="bg_green">0</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td class="bg_green">0</td>
                                    <td class="bg_yellow">0</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td class="bg_green">0</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td class="bg_green">0</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td class="bg_green">0</td>
                                    <td class="bg_yellow">0</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td class="bg_yellow">0</td>
                                    <td>0</td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td class="bg_yellow"></td>
                                    <td class="bg_yellow"></td>
                                    <td class="bg_yellow"></td>
                                    <td class="bg_yellow">0</td>
                                    <td class="bg_yellow"></td>
                                    <td class="bg_yellow"></td>
                                    <td class="bg_yellow"></td>
                                    <td class="bg_yellow"></td>
                                    <td class="bg_yellow"></td>
                                    <td class="bg_yellow"></td>
                                    <td class="bg_yellow">0</td>
                                    <td class="bg_yellow"></td>
                                    <td class="bg_yellow"></td>
                                    <td class="bg_yellow"></td>
                                    <td class="bg_yellow">0</td>
                                    <td class="bg_yellow">0</td>
                                    <td class="bg_yellow"></td>
                                    <td class="bg_yellow"></td>
                                    <td class="bg_yellow"></td>
                                    <td class="bg_yellow">0</td>
                                    <td class="bg_yellow"></td>
                                    <td class="bg_yellow"></td>
                                    <td class="bg_yellow"></td>
                                    <td class="bg_yellow"></td>
                                    <td class="bg_yellow"></td>
                                    <td class="bg_yellow"></td>
                                    <td class="bg_yellow">0</td>
                                    <td class="bg_yellow"></td>
                                    <td class="bg_yellow"></td>
                                    <td class="bg_yellow"></td>
                                    <td class="bg_yellow">0</td>
                                    <td class="bg_yellow">0</td>
                                    <td class="bg_yellow"></td>
                                    <td class="bg_yellow"></td>
                                    <td class="bg_yellow"></td>
                                    <td class="bg_yellow">0</td>
                                    <td class="bg_yellow">0</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>

    <script src="../dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../dist/jquery.table2excel.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("body").on("click","button",function(){
            exportExcel();
        });
        function exportExcel(){
            $(".table").table2excel({
                exclude: ".noExl",//不导出的表格数据选择器，不导出的数据加class加上 noExl就可以了
                name: "Excel Document Name",
                filename: "myFileName",
                fileext: ".xls",
                exclude_img: true,
                exclude_links: true,
                exclude_inputs: true
            });
        }
    })
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please make sure the HTML element text and comments are all translated to English, and add an explanation of what this is supposed to accomplish and how.