# Exporting only filtered data from JQuery datatable to Excel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Is there an easy way to export data to Excel from a JQuery Table after the user does filtering on a column or columns.

Please any body can answer ?

Comment: please provide your sample code

Comment: Adapt code from http://stackoverflow.com/a/24081343/989350 by filtering out rows in `for` loop.

Comment: i need 10 reputations to post the image, i think image will clear the picture. how can i upload image ?

Comment: you can generate `CSV`  file which will be open in Excel