# Exporting selected html rows and columns in excel

Tags: javascript, excel, razor, model-view-controller

I am having a small project on MVC Razor.Well,I have an html table from which I want to just select any rows with checkbox click and then export those selected rows in Excel.Also,my table has 4 columns but I want only 2 columns from it to be exported.
 Now how can I achieve it?I tried all things like using scripting etc. but all in vain.Can I apply style to data exported in excel?

Comment: Please share data definions and example data as well as what you've tried

Answer (score 0):

If i am not mistaken, it looks like you want to export an HTML table to excel, and these are some of the links i found that could help:

[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22317951/export-html-table-data-to-excel-using-javascript-jquery-is-not-working-properl)

[jQuery](http://www.jqueryscript.net/table/Export-Html-Table-To-Excel-Spreadsheet-using-jQuery-table2excel.html)

Comment: I have gone through these links but, I want to specifically select rows using checkbox and then export only those many to excel.In these links whole table is being exported along with all the columns.