# Export to Excel is not working if table contains more than 500 rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, export, export-to-excel

I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22317951/export-html-table-data-to-excel-using-javascript-jquery-is-not-working-properl)

page and implemented export to excel feature..

It is working fine if my table contains 500 rows. But it is not working if it has more than that. How to make it work for large amount of data.

Please advice..

Thanks in advance - 
Chitra

Comment: Works fine... https://jsfiddle.net/dhw7sxo6/ Also, poorly asked question. No details, no specifics. Please clarify.

Comment: No error(in Developer tool console). When ever I click Export to Excel button, it is opening a new blank tab and nothing is happening..page is unresponsive for few seconds and back to normal..Not exporting table data.

Comment: @Urbz, the page which I have mentioned contains the code for Export html table to Excel, I have implemented that code in my Asp.net application and it was working fine when table has less number of rows. But when row count exceeds 500 the export functionality was not working. any suggestion..

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Infragistics DataGrid, the Excel export default is related to page size, 500 rows. To Export all rows, need to disable Pager, then bind data to the grid again, then call the export function.  Review the Row count from Add Watch to assure the count is correct.

```
[![Protected Sub WebImageButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As ButtonEventArgs) Handles WebImageButton1.Click
    WebDataGrid1.Behaviors.Paging.Enabled = False
    WebDataGrid1.DataBind()
    WebExcelExporter1.Export(WebDataGrid1)
    WebDataGrid1.Behaviors.Paging.Enabled = True
End Sub][1]][1]
```