# save html as xls - JS save dialog error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, excel, export

I am referring to the script posted by @bettelbursche from this topic:
[Export html table data to Excel using JavaScript / JQuery is not working properly in chrome browse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22317951/export-html-table-data-to-excel-using-javascript-jquery-is-not-working-properl)
(Note: I cant reply there because I have not reached the minimum amount of postings needed)

I am trying to save a displayed HTML table **only** as XLS which is working, however, after clicking the Save button, the generated file is being named "download" (Chrome) or "unknown" (Safari), missing the file extension and also triggering a warning by Excel when opening the renamed download.xls file.

The problem seems to be in this line:

```
sa = txtArea1.document.execCommand("SaveAs", true, "DataTableExport.xls");
```

Full script below:

```
        <script>
    function fnExcelReport()
    {
        var tab_text = '<table border="1px" style="font-size:10px" ">';
        var textRange; 
        var j = 0;
        var tab = document.getElementById('export'); // id of table
        var lines = tab.rows.length;

        // the first headline of the table
        if (lines > 0) {
            tab_text = tab_text + '<tr bgcolor="#DFDFDF">' + tab.rows[0].innerHTML + '</tr>';
        }

        // table data lines, loop starting from 1
        for (j = 1 ; j < lines; j++) {     
            tab_text = tab_text + "<tr>" + tab.rows[j].innerHTML + "</tr>";
        }

        tab_text = tab_text + "</table>";
        tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<A[^>]*>|<\/A>/g, "");             //remove if u want links in your table
        tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<img[^>]*>/gi,"");                 // remove if u want images in your table
        tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<input[^>]*>|<\/input>/gi, "");    // reomves input params
        // console.log(tab_text); // aktivate so see the result (press F12 in browser)

        var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
        var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE "); 

         // if Internet Explorer
        if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) {
            txtArea1.document.open("txt/html","replace");
            txtArea1.document.write(tab_text);
            txtArea1.document.close();
            txtArea1.focus();
            sa = txtArea1.document.execCommand("SaveAs", true, "DataTableExport.xls");
        }  
        else // other browser not tested on IE 11
            sa = window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text));  

        return (sa);
    } 
    </script>
```

I suspected that Chrome depreciated the Save As dialogue but cannot find any documentation on that. Funny is that the problem is triggered across all browsers on both MAC / PC. Would appreciate some insight on this please ;)

Comment: Related: [Is there any way to specify a suggested filename when using data: URI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283956/is-there-any-way-to-specify-a-suggested-filename-when-using-data-uri)

Comment: Does not initiate the JS function, no reaction after clicking on the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is not on the line you identified. That piece of code is for Internet Explorer, as explained in the code comments.

The issue is here:

```
sa = window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text));
```

Nothing is telling the browser what to name the file and nothing establishes any file extension. You can fix this by implementing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16523173/704944) or, even more related because you linked to the question originally, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27843359/704944) into your code by replacing the line I've identified above is.

To do that, replace:

```
 else // other browser not tested on IE 11
            sa = window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text));
```

With:

```
else { // other browser not tested on IE 11
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.download = "DataTableExport.xls";
    link.href = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text);
    link.click();
}
```

Comment: I can live with the excel warning message, but how can I define the filename and extension for the above code?

Comment: @Armitage2k Check the second answer I linked to.

Comment: I did run the script in the second answer but all that does is create an empty excel file. The problem I have is I dont know how to tell that script that I has to get the content from <table id="export">.

Comment: Thanks!! Using IE<=9  The above code is forcing the user to save the excel, before viewing it. It will be very useful, if there a way to view the excel using "Open With" option, so that the file can be view without saving it? Like Example : jsfiddle.net/lesson8/jWAJ7 (in example fiddle- when the export button is clicked, the browser shows a dialog box with options open with and save file)
Thanks in Advance.