# How to export datagrid to excel?

Tags: javascript, php, excel, export

I have been trying to export datagrid to excel using php. I want to make like this: [Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/dqaq4amg/).

But when i create, it doesn't work. This is my code.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="../m3/jquery-3.1.1.min.js">
   $("#btnExport").click(function (e) {
    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + $('#dvData').html());
    e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="btnExport" value=" Export Table data into Excel " />
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="dvData">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Column One</th>
            <th>Column Two</th>
            <th>Column Three</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>row1 Col1</td>
            <td>row1 Col2</td>
            <td>row1 Col3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>row2 Col1</td>
            <td>row2 Col2</td>
            <td>row2 Col3</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please take a look at :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22317951/export-html-table-data-to-excel-using-javascript-jquery-is-not-working-properl.

Comment: @SyedFasih Thank you. I'll look into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

  $("#btnExport").click(function (e) {
    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + $('#dvData').html());
    e.preventDefault();
});
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="btnExport" value=" Export Table data into Excel " />
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="dvData">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Column One</th>
            <th>Column Two</th>
            <th>Column Three</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>row1 Col1</td>
            <td>row1 Col2</td>
            <td>row1 Col3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>row2 Col1</td>
            <td>row2 Col2</td>
            <td>row2 Col3</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

//open a jquery to run the click event

```
$(function(){
  $("#btnExport").click(function (e) {
      window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + $('#dvData').html());
      e.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks.. it works now.. but inside excel file still generated html tag. <table>, <tr> <td>.. do u know how to get rid this off?

Comment: hi @Teddy can u send me your code and a screenshot of your output, it work fine for me, i cant replicate your problem