# Export to excel not working in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, html, excel

Hi i use this code to make an export on my HTML table to excel, but it not working in IE 11. Can somebody help me please?

```
    var tableToExcel = (function() {
  var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
    , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
    , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
    , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
  return function(table, name) {
    if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
    var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
    window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
  }
})()
```

Comment: How is your question related to PHP? Btw, just saying "not working" with out any explanation usually doesn't sit well with people here.

Comment: Check accepted answer on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22317951/export-html-table-data-to-excel-using-javascript-jquery-is-not-working-properl

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
<a table_div='ExportcommunicationPlanDiv' class="btnExport"><li title="Export to Excel"><div class="btn-excel"> </div></li></a>

<script>

    var excelfileName="download";
 $(".btnExport").click(function () {

     var today = new Date();
     var dd = today.getDate();
     var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!

     var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
     if(dd<10){
         dd='0'+dd;
     } 
     if(mm<10){
         mm='0'+mm;
     } 
     var today = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;

     excelfileName = $('#POTS_CKT_ID').val() +"_"+today;
    // var todaysDate = moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY');
    if(isIE())
        {

        var id = $(this).attr('table_div');
        var blobURL = tableToExcelForIE(''+id+'');
        }
    else
        {
        //var todaysDate ="test";
        var id = $(this).attr('table_div');
        var blobURL = tableToExcel(''+id+'');
        $(this).attr('download',excelfileName+'.xls')
        $(this).attr('href',blobURL);
        }

    });
function isIE()
 {
     var isIE11 = navigator.userAgent.indexOf(".NET CLR") > -1;      
     var isIE11orLess = isIE11 || navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE") != -1;
     return isIE11orLess;
 }
 var tableToExcel = (function() {
      var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
        , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8"/></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
        , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
        , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
      return function(table, name) {
        if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
        var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
        var blob = new Blob([format(template, ctx)]);
        var blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        return blobURL;
      }
    })()


     var tableToExcelForIE = (function() {

          var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
            , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8"/></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
            , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
            , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
          return function(table, name) {
            if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
            var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
            var blob = new Blob([format(template, ctx)]);
            var blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            //IE
                if (isIE()) {
                  csvData = table.innerHTML;
                    if (window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {
                        var blob = new Blob([format(template, ctx)], {
                            type: "text/html"
                        });
                       navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, ''+excelfileName+'.xls');

                    }

                }
          }
        })()
  </script>
```

Comment: While this may solve the problem, you should explain how and why it solves the issue.

Comment: This part got is what really mattered.  
if (window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {
                        var blob = new Blob([format(template, ctx)], {
                            type: "text/html"
                        });
                       navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, ''+excelfileName+'.xls');

                    }

Answer (score 0):

```
It is Working Good .
in html code
<a table_div='ExportcommunicationPlanDiv' class="btnExport"><li title="Export to Excel"><div class="btn-excel"> </div></li></a>

<script>

    var excelfileName="download";
 $(".btnExport").click(function () {

     var today = new Date();
     var dd = today.getDate();
     var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!

     var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
     if(dd<10){
         dd='0'+dd;
     } 
     if(mm<10){
         mm='0'+mm;
     } 
     var today = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;

     excelfileName = excelfileName +"_"+today;
    // var todaysDate = moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY');
    if(isIE())
        {

        var id = $(this).attr('table_div');
        var blobURL = tableToExcelForIE(''+id+'');
        }
    else
        {
        //var todaysDate ="test";
        var id = $(this).attr('table_div');
        var blobURL = tableToExcel(''+id+'');
        $(this).attr('download',excelfileName+'.xls')
        $(this).attr('href',blobURL);
        }

    });
function isIE()
 {
     var isIE11 = navigator.userAgent.indexOf(".NET CLR") > -1;      
     var isIE11orLess = isIE11 || navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE") != -1;
     return isIE11orLess;
 }
 var tableToExcel = (function() {
      var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
        , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8"/></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
        , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
        , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
      return function(table, name) {
        if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
        var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
        var blob = new Blob([format(template, ctx)]);
        var blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        return blobURL;
      }
    })()


     var tableToExcelForIE = (function() {

          var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
            , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8"/></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
            , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
            , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
          return function(table, name) {
            if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
            var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
            var blob = new Blob([format(template, ctx)]);
            var blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            //IE
                if (isIE()) {
                  csvData = table.innerHTML;
                    if (window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {
                        var blob = new Blob([format(template, ctx)], {
                            type: "text/html"
                        });
                       navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, ''+excelfileName+'.xls');

                    }

                }
          }
        })()
  </script>
```