# SharePoint export to excel is not working in google chrome

Tags: sharepoint, office365

SharePoint Export to Excel is not working in Google Chrome, while it is working fine in Internet Explorer.

I am using Office 365 site and after clicking on the export button i am seeing below message:

```
WEB
1
https://site/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?XMLDATA=1&List={88B6B725-0CF2-4836-8837-756E1458D5DE}&View={6BCBC19D-6BAC-4D72-BCB5-017007177ADC}&RowLimit=0&RootFolder=%2fsites%2fFinance%2fLists%2fGL%20Master



Selection={88B6B725-0CF2-4836-8837-756E1458D5DE}-{6BCBC19D-6BAC-4D72-BCB5-017007177ADC}
EditWebPage=
Formatting=None
PreFormattedTextToColumns=True
ConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne=True
SingleBlockTextImport=False
DisableDateRecognition=False
DisableRedirections=False
SharePointApplication=https://bramblesgroup.sharepoint.com/sites/Finance/_vti_bin
SharePointListView={6BCBC19D-6BAC-4D72-BCB5-017007177ADC}
SharePointListName={88B6B725-0CF2-4836-8837-756E1458D5DE}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on sharepoint.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2):

In SharePoint, `Export To Excel` functionality is supported only in IE browser.
This functionality requires Active X control which Chrome and Firefox doesn't support.

You can find more details on this [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263526(v=office.15).aspx#supportmatrix)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for  your help, but client need that export should work in all browser. Any help?

Comment: Thats the default behaviour of SharePoint and it is accepted across industry.

Comment: I guess it works fine in Firefox, issue only in Chrome Browser.

Answer (score 1):

Buddy, you're going to have to ***use an alternative method*** because SharePoint's Export to Excel feature will give you the user experience you desire only within Internet Explorer 8, 9, and 10, per Microsoft's own documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/install/browser-support-planning#supportmatrix. However, ***the answer given in this other StackOverflow question might be just what you need because it does work in Chrome:***

- [Export html table data to Excel using JavaScript / JQuery is not working properly in chrome browse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22317951/export-html-table-data-to-excel-using-javascript-jquery-is-not-working-properl)

The answer basically involves the use of a custom JavaScript function to present similar functionality to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Export to Excel will not work in Chrome for some lists as it requires a compatible application. Alternatively, you could view in QUICK VIEW – or “edit the list” and while in this view, copy and paste the data to Excel.

There is one reference article which will help you to understand the limitations of SharePoint in Google Chrome, Please [Click Here](http://www.sharethepoint.com/chrome-limitations-with-sharepoint-2013/) to view that article.