# How to convert a HTMLtable to a CSV file using JQuery

Tags: html, html-table, export-to-csv

I was searching for a solution on how to convert a HTML table to an EXCEL file. The link of solution is this : [Export html table data to Excel using JavaScript / JQuery is not working properly in chrome browse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22317951/export-html-table-data-to-excel-using-javascript-jquery-is-not-working-properl/24081343#24081343)

OR the codes:

```
$('#btnExport').click(function () {
            fnExcelReport();
            function fnExcelReport() {
                var tab_text = "<table border='2px'><tr bgcolor='#87AFC6'>";
                var textRange; var j = 0;
                tab = document.getElementById('table1'); // id of table

                for (j = 0; j < tab.rows.length; j++) {
                    tab_text = tab_text + tab.rows[j].innerHTML + "</tr>";
                    //tab_text=tab_text+"</tr>";
                }

                tab_text = tab_text + "</table>";
                tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<A[^>]*>|<\/A>/g, "");//remove if u want links in your table
                tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<img[^>]*>/gi, ""); // remove if u want images in your table
                tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<input[^>]*>|<\/input>/gi, ""); // reomves input params

                var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
                var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

                if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))      // If Internet Explorer
                {
                    txtArea1.document.open("txt/html", "replace");
                    txtArea1.document.write(tab_text);
                    txtArea1.document.close();
                    txtArea1.focus();
                    sa = txtArea1.document.execCommand("SaveAs", true, "QI.csv");
                }
                else                 //other browser not tested on IE 11
                    sa = window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text));

                return (sa);
            }
        });
```

Now I need to Convert HTML table to CSV file. I tried to change the file extention .xls to .csv and it didn't work. Can anyone help me to convert to csv file?

Comment: have look http://jsfiddle.net/insin/cmewv/

Comment: Try your code with change this snippet 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8'

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the replies. Really appreciate it. But when I change the snippet to as above, it shows an invalid extension and an invalid data. Maybe it doesn't change to .CSV format. Is there any other way?

Comment: Thanks to all who helped me. Finally it worked by using ExcellentExport.js v1.4 from the 2nd solution from the link : stackoverflow.com/questions/15547198/export-html-table-to-cs‌​v