# How to Download table data as excel sheet using php..?

Tags: javascript, php, excel

**Guys i'm generating a set of data in a table after som set of calculation.. as soon as user clicks save button excel file with that data must be generated for downloading..**

**What is the php code for that ..**

**guys the data is not retrieved from database...its being displayed after a set of calculation as been performed.**

**Since i dont have any idea ive not posted any related code...sry for that..**

**below is how my table looks like**

https://ibb.co/mUMOrQ

**below is my table code**

```
       <div id="myModal" class="modal fade in">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <a class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
                <div class="table-title">
                <h3>CUF Table</h3>
                </div>
                <table class="table-fill" id="tabid">
                <thead>
            </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
        <tr>
        <th class="text-left">TimeStamp</th>
        <th class="text-left">CUF</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="table-hover">
        <!--tr>
        <td class="text-left" id="data"></td>
        <td class="text-left" id="data1"></td>
        </tr-->
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

     <div class="modal-footer">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button id="change-chart"  class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span>Save</button>
                  </div>
      </div>
      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

**Below is jquery that ive included to download the file**

```
     $("#BUTTON").click(function(){
     $("#TABLE").table2excel({
     // exclude CSS class
    exclude: ".noExl",
    name: "Data",
    filename: "Data" //do not include extension
   });
   });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one of the following

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38761185/5350773

http://www.jqueryscript.net/table/Export-Html-Table-To-Excel-Spreadsheet-using-jQuery-table2excel.html

Comment: ..ive downloaded the jquery script...But it contains so many files..can u tell me which file to include...

Comment: this one only in src/jquery.table2excel.js

Comment: i did include that folder...but as soon as i click my save button it didnt do anything..??

Comment: you should check demo on how to use this js in _demo_ folder of zip

Comment: @ Zaheer Attar..ill post my table code wait....that demo is of no use..theyve not mentioned anything in that..