# How to write array of data i.e, present in console part to excel sheet in react js

Tags: reactjs

Basically, project where some application is uploaded in the form of pdf , done with the parsing of
data in json and now the array of data should be displayed in excel.

Comment: Needs more information. Maybe show something that you have done so far?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22317951/export-html-table-data-to-excel-using-javascript-jquery-is-not-working-properl