# How export excel with StatusBar

Tags: vue.js, ag-grid

I don't know how to export this statusPanels.
I have a panel in the bottom position with big summary data. How can I export it to excel?
[image]

Comment: This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/q/22317951/12696223