# Exporting Html Table containing hyperlinks to CSV by persisting the hyperlinks in csv file

Tags: javascript, html, csv, html-table, export-to-csv

I want to export the html table to csv file. In my case Html table consists of hyperlinks. While exporting html table to csv either the text or link is getting persisted in the table. I want the text to be persisted in the csv file as a hyperlink. Explored multiple solutions but none works. Tried adding whole anchor tag to variable and then adding to row, but whole anchor tag is appearing in the table in csv file. Needed quick help.

[This is how the csv file should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziA7j.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <center>
        <h1 style="color:green">GeeksForGeeks</h1>
        <h2>Table to CSV converter</h2>
        <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>age</th>
                <th>place</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/how+to+get+href+value+of+anchor+tag+in+jquery+in+list">Laxman</a></td>
                <td>19</td>
                <td>Hyderabad</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Dhoni</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>Ranchi</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Kohli</td>
                <td>25</td>
                <td>Delhi</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br><br>
        <button type="button" onclick="tableToCSV()">
            download CSV
        </button>
    </center>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function tableToCSV() {

            // Variable to store the final csv data
            var csv_data = [];

            // Get each row data
            var rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {

                // Get each column data
                var cols = rows[i].querySelectorAll('td,th');

                // Stores each csv row data
                var csvrow = [];
                for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {

                    // Get the text data of each cell
                    // of a row and push it to csvrow
                    var links = cols[j].getElementsByTagName('a');
                    if (links.length > 0) {
                        var link = links[0].getAttribute('href');
                        var text = cols[j].textContent;
                        var result = text.link(link)
                        csvrow.push(result);
                       
                    } else {
                        var cellData = cols[j].textContent;
                        csvrow.push(cellData);
                        
                    }
                
                }

                // Combine each column value with comma
                csv_data.push(csvrow.join(","));
            }

            // Combine each row data with new line character
            csv_data = csv_data.join('\n');

            // Call this function to download csv file
            downloadCSVFile(csv_data);

        }

        function downloadCSVFile(csv_data) {

            // Create CSV file object and feed
            // our csv_data into it
            CSVFile = new Blob([csv_data], {
                type: "text/csv"
            });

            // Create to temporary link to initiate
            // download process
            var temp_link = document.createElement('a');

            // Download csv file
            temp_link.download = "GfG.csv";
            var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(CSVFile);
            temp_link.href = url;

            // This link should not be displayed
            temp_link.style.display = "none";
            document.body.appendChild(temp_link);

            // Automatically click the link to
            // trigger download
            temp_link.click();
            document.body.removeChild(temp_link);
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? You want `<a href="https://my.link"></a>` to be `https://my.link` only? Can you post what the final .csv should look like?

Comment: @Priya csv file isn't HTML, it's plain text, you can't have live working links on them, nor will any HTML render on a csv file.

Comment: @obscure Thanks for your reply. CSV file should look same as HTML table in the output. On clicking Laxman, it should redirect to the url. Only Laxman should be visible in csv file, holding the hyperlink. It need not be exactly csv file even excel is also fine.

Comment: @Priya Well, as zer00ne said, CSV is just plain text - it's the target application you try to load the .csv file into that needs to make sense of the data. Do you want to import it into Excel and have working hyperlinks there?

Comment: @obscure excel is also fine. Tried this solution -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22317951/export-html-table-data-to-excel-using-javascript-jquery-is-not-working-properl, it works fine for me, any other better solution than this ?