# Export HTML Table to MS Excel 2010

Tags: javascript, html, excel-2010

I am trying to get my html table in a MS Excel document and I have tried many examples from here and internet but most of them didn't work. Mostly I can download a .xls file and when excel opens that file it comes nothing (not even standard Excel grid). And when I open the `.xls` files with Notepad, I can see that file actually holds values.

Most of the comments in previous questions were telling they work but these question dates are also little bit old and I can't tell if I am having version problems.

For example [Javascript to export html table to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17142427/javascript-to-export-html-table-to-excel) , I can download an Excel file but can't see values in it.

Also [this](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html) DataTables example work well for me but I don't need all the stuff they provide like searching and listing.

Please let me know if any of you had such trouble and how did you solve them.

Comment: "none of them works" ... "DataTables example work well for me"???

Answer (score 0):

You have a solution (by your own admission): DataTables.  Any features you don't need can be turned off or just not used.

Comment: yeah, but it still does not explain why i got problems after previous attempts with javascript

Comment: Maybe you did something wrong in code you couldn't be bothered to post?  Debugging questions usually include what needs to be debugged.