# How to Download data in excel from Angular 4

Tags: excel, angular, service

I am building an angular app in which i need to export Table data in an excel file.
I have a ride success component inside which i have a table which is displaying data fetched through an angular service.
Now i need to download this table data in an excel file from my browser.

ridesuccess Component:-

```
export class RideSuccessComponent implements OnInit {



 p = 1;
  myForm: FormGroup;
  rideSuccess: RideSuccess[];
  rsuccess: RideSuccess = '';
  constructor(private adminService: AdminService) {}



 ngOnInit() {

    this.rsuccess = '';

    this.adminService.getRideSuccess()
    .subscribe(
        (rideSuccess: RideSuccess[]) => {
            this.rideSuccess = rideSuccess;
        }
    );
```

ridesuccess HTML:-

```
    <table class="responstable" id="responsetable">

  <tr>
    <th data-th="Driver details"><span>Driver name</span></th>
    <th>Rider Name</th>
    <th>Pool ID</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
    <th>Source</th>
    <th>Destination</th>
    <th>Sum ID</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

  <tr *ngFor="let ridesuccess of rideSuccess| paginate: { itemsPerPage: 5, currentPage: p }; let i = index" >
    <td>{{ridesuccess.driverName}}</td>
    <td>{{ridesuccess.riderName}}</td>
    <td>{{ridesuccess.poolId}}</td>
    <td>{{ridesuccess.amount}}</td>
    <td>{{ridesuccess.source}}</td>
    <td>{{ridesuccess.destination}}</td>
    <td>{{ridesuccess.sumId}}</td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" (click)="setmodal(ridesuccess)">Gratify</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<pagination-controls (pageChange)="p = $event" class="my-pagination" style="float: right"></pagination-controls>
```

Now i want to implement a button in HTML, which on clicked will download the full table data in an excel file.

NOTE:- I have all data in my angular service(**getRideSuccess()**). I want to download data from my angular object which is getting populated using the service(**getRideSuccess()**).

Package.json :-

```
  {
  "name": "pagination",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "build": "del-cli public/js/app && webpack --config webpack.config.dev.js --progress --profile --watch",
    "build:prod": "del-cli public/js/app && ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json && ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json && webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js --progress --profile --bail && del-cli 'public/js/app/**/*.js' 'public/js/app/**/*.js.map' '!public/js/app/bundle.js' '!public/js/app/*.chunk.js' 'assets/app/**/*.ngfactory.ts' 'assets/app/**/*.shim.ts' 'assets/app/**/*.ngsummary.json' 'assets/app/**/*.ngstyle.ts'"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "^4.0.0",
    "angular2-bootstrap-confirm": "^1.0.4",
    "angular2-csv": "^0.2.5",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "~1.15.2",
    "chart.js": "^2.5.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "~4.14.0",
    "hbs": "~3.1.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^7.4.0",
    "mongoose": "^4.9.6",
    "mongoose-sequence-plugin": "^1.0.5",
    "mongoose-unique-validator": "^1.0.5",
    "morgan": "~1.6.1",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.5.0",
    "ngx-pagination": "^3.0.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "^5.2.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0",
    "shortid": "^2.2.8",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/core-js": "0.9.36",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.45",
    "angular-router-loader": "^0.5.0",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.5.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "del-cli": "^0.2.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.4",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "ts-loader": "^2.0.3",
    "typescript": "^2.1.4",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "main": "app.js",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}
```

Comment: you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17142427/javascript-to-export-html-table-to-excel)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may need to use `angular2-csv` library in order to do this.
`npm install --save angular2-csv`

```
import { Angular2Csv } from 'angular2-csv/Angular2-csv';


    export class RideSuccessComponent implements OnInit {
        ...
        rideSuccess: RideSuccess[];
        ...
        exportData() {

            new Angular2Csv(this.rideSuccess, 'My Report');

        }
        ...
    }
```

Then just call `exportData` function whenever you want. Additional info [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-csv).

Comment: I tried using Angular2csv module for the same. However, after implementing my browser throws an error like:-  Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'Angular2Csv' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.  What can be the issue??  I have also edited my question and added my package.json also for reference.

Comment: we don't need to add the reference in module , use it directly in the component for Angular2CSV

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this using **DataTableModule** provided by PrimeNG [DataTableModule Example](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable).

As for the Angular2Csv issue, i found that it throws **UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY angular 4.3.3** while installing the module. However, i am using **Angular 4.0.0** for development. It seems the latest version of **Angular2Csv** requires 4.3.3 hence the error.