# how to export a table inside php tag in to excel and pdf?

Tags: php

Using the id how to export the table in to excel and pdf

```
<?php
echo "<table id="report">";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>";
echo "test";
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
<button id="export">Export</button>
?>
```

Comment: Syntax issues... escape the `"` by putting a \ behind the `"`. You're missing an `echo` before your last `<button` aswell

Comment: @BenoîtLatinier I want it to be exported using the id

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by "using the id". By the way do you seek to do it server side or client side? Some js solutions exists too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17142427/javascript-to-export-html-table-to-excel

Comment: Is there a way to use the id report and produce an excel

Answer (score -1):

you have a couple of options on each, some of which are these.   There is though, no 'magic' wand method.

**excel**

use the most excellent [PHPSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet) (formerly PHPExcel)

for pdf

**wkhtmltopdf**

Use [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/).  This requires that you have server root access but allows you to dump in HTML and get a PDF out that looks the same as the webpage would have done.

Wkhtmltopdf will also process CSS and parse js.  So its very useful for making pdf's from dynamic output.