# How to create CSV file in vue.js

Tags: csv, vuejs2

I have tried to create CSV file in vue.js.  server send readyment data which is we can directly write data in csv file. data from server response is

```
head1, head2, head3, head4
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
```

This is my response formate from the server. I want to write this data in CSV format and give download CSV functionality.

Any Idea about create and write a file in vue.js?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript to export html table to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17142427/javascript-to-export-html-table-to-excel)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got my answer by using javascript.

Below is my javascript function for download csv

```
downloadCSV(jsonData){
    const arr = typeof jsonData !== 'object' ? JSON.parse(jsonData) : jsonData;
    const str = `${Object.keys(arr[0]).map((value) => `${value}`).join(',')}\r\n`;
    const csvContent = arr.reduce((st, next) => {
      st += `${Object.values(next).map((value) => 
        `${value}`).join(',')}\r\n`;
         return st;
      }, str);
    const element = document.createElement('a');
    element.href = `data:text/csv;charset=utf8,${encodeURI(csvContent)}`;
    element.target = '_blank';
    element.download = 'export.csv';
    element.click();    }
```

value of data is in CSV format data

```
col1, col2, col3
row1-value1, row1-value2, row1-value3
```

Comment: What is `Utils.makeTextFile`?)

Comment: What is Utils.maketextFile ?? its undefined .

Comment: Function Added in Answer.

Comment: try to put the exact working code you used. Because I am pretty sure that is not it.

Comment: Added exact working code, removed the makeTextFile function, and writen all code in a single function.