# Export data of table in CSV, Excel, PDF format in VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, export

I am working on vueJs template and I need to export data of tables in three formats which are .pdf, .csv, .xls
I tried with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53444213/how-to-create-csv-file-in-vue-js/53663695) but its show Utils undefined. so how can I achieve what I want ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Easy way**

If you can use different table component try to look into [Vue materialize datatable](https://github.com/MicroDroid/vue-materialize-datatable)

It's letting you to export in XLS and print to PDF

**Without any component**

The way I personally use If i need to export any JSON that is consist of more fields than there are in the actual table:

https://www.papaparse.com/

```
import Papa from "papaparse";
```

```
var blob = new Blob([Papa.unparse(jsonData)], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;' });

var link = document.createElement("a");

var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
link.setAttribute("href", url);
link.setAttribute("download", 'filename.csv');
link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
document.body.removeChild(link);
```

So, we actually unparsing JSON data into the blob, creating dynamic element which linked to it and downloading the file.

Comment: Any recommendations on how to write a unit test for this?

Comment: @Tom sorry, hadn't written any unit tests for this