# HTML table to excel using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, excel, html-table

May i know how to press a button and download an excel(.xlsx), the excel will need to contain all the values. Some of the table is an input, need to download the input value.

My html code look like this:

```
<table id="tabledata" border=1>
<tr><td>X</td><td>Y</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td class="tabledatacell"><input type="text" onkeyup="" id="dataX1"></td><td class="tabledatacell"><input type="text" onkeyup="" id="dataY1"></td><td><button onclick="remove(1)">Remove</button></td></tr>
<tr><td class="tabledatacell"><input type="text" onkeyup="" id="dataX2"></td><td class="tabledatacell"><input type="text" onkeyup="" id="dataY2"></td><td><button onclick="remove(2)">Remove</button></td></tr>
<tr><td class="tabledatacell"><input type="text" onkeyup="" id="dataX3"></td><td class="tabledatacell"><input type="text" onkeyup="" id="dataY3"></td><td><button onclick="remove(3)">Remove</button></td></tr>
<tr><td class="tabledatacell"><input type="text" onkeyup="" id="dataX4"></td><td class="tabledatacell"><input type="text" onkeyup="" id="dataY4"></td><td><button onclick="remove(4)">Remove</button></td></tr>
<tr><td class="tabledatacell"><input type="text" onkeyup="" id="dataX5"></td><td class="tabledatacell"><input type="text" onkeyup="" id="dataY5"></td><td><button onclick="remove(5)">Remove</button></td></tr>
<tr><td class="tabledatacell"><input type="text" onkeyup="" id="dataX6"></td><td class="tabledatacell"><input type="text" onkeyup="" id="dataY6"></td><td><button onclick="remove(6)">Remove</button></td></tr>
<tr><td class="tabledatacell"><input type="text" onkeyup="" id="dataX7"></td><td class="tabledatacell"><input type="text" onkeyup="" id="dataY7"></td><td><button onclick="remove(7)">Remove</button></td></tr>
<tr><td class="tabledatacell"><input type="text" onkeyup="" id="dataX8"></td><td class="tabledatacell"><input type="text" onkeyup="" id="dataY8"></td><td><button onclick="remove(8)">Remove</button></td></tr>
<tr><td class="tabledatacell"><input type="text" onkeyup="" id="dataX9"></td><td class="tabledatacell"><input type="text" onkeyup="" id="dataY9"></td><td><button onclick="remove(9)">Remove</button></td></tr>
<tr><td class="tabledatacell"><input type="text" onkeyup="" id="dataX10"></td><td class="tabledatacell"><input type="text" onkeyup="" id="dataY10"></td><td><button onclick="remove(10")>Remove</button></td></tr>
<tr><td class="tabledatacell"><input type="text" onkeyup="" id="dataX11"></td><td class="tabledatacell"><input type="text" onkeyup="" id="dataY11"></td><td><button onclick="remove(11)">Remove</button></td></tr>
<tr><td class="tabledatacell"><input type="text" onkeyup="" id="dataX12"></td><td class="tabledatacell"><input type="text" onkeyup="" id="dataY12"></td><td><button onclick="remove(12)">Remove</button></td></tr>
<tr><td class="tabledatacell"><input type="text" onkeyup="" id="dataX13"></td><td class="tabledatacell"><input type="text" onkeyup="" id="dataY13"></td><td><button onclick="remove(13)">Remove</button></td></tr>
<tr><td class="tabledatacell"><input type="text" onkeyup="" id="dataX14"></td><td class="tabledatacell"><input type="text" onkeyup="" id="dataY14"></td><td><button onclick="remove(14)">Remove</button></td></tr>
<tr><td class="tabledatacell"><input type="text"onkeyup=""  id="dataX15"></td><td class="tabledatacell"><input type="text" onkeyup="" id="dataY15"></td><td><button onclick="remove(15)">Remove</button></td></tr>
</table>
</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Is this a solution for you:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17142427/javascript-to-export-html-table-to-excel

Comment: @marcelo when i download press the export button  it download a non-excel file.

Comment: does this code work and if does where do i insert this code?

filename = filename?filename+'.xls':'excel_data.xls';