# Google Analytics Embed API - save report as xls file

Tags: javascript, python, plone, google-analytics-api, google-reporting-api

I use GA Embed API (https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/) to add some reports in my plone website.
Have you any idea how to save these reports (or report tables) in xls format?

I want to add an Export button near each report that will export chart content that can be changed with some query filters. A solution for table reports would be perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found some solutions here:
[Export dynamic html table to excel in javascript in firefox browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6955627/export-dynamic-html-table-to-excel-in-javascript-in-firefox-browser)
[Javascript to export html table to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17142427/javascript-to-export-html-table-to-excel)
[HTML Table to Excel Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17126453/html-table-to-excel-javascript)

Better to export from GA.
Export for Excel is possible from custom reports (downloaded or sent to email).
Also we can schedule custom reports to be sent via email on one of the following schedules:
- Once
- Daily (sent each morning)
- Weekly (sent the day of the week you select)
- Monthly (sent the day of the month you select)
- Quarterly (sent first day of each quarter
(https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1038573?hl=en)