# Export html table to Excel javascript function special characters changed

Tags: javascript, excel, encoding, export, special-characters

I have the following function that exports an html to excel:

```
function generateexcel(tableid) {
  var table= document.getElementById(tableid);
  var html = table.outerHTML;
  window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(html));
}
```

One problem is that the especial characters in the data are transformed to other symbols:

- 1º = 1Âº
- é = Ã©

How would you fix this? Is there any character replace to the html to prevent it? Any encoding option?

Comment: Have you tried adding an explicit encoding declaration to the media type? `data:application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=UTF-8`

Comment: Yep it was one of the solutions i found and tried before asking here, it didnt work with the different charsets i tried... Details here: http://www.weblogism.com/item/270/why-does-e-become-a and http://www.weblogism.com/item/271/why-does-e-become-a-ii

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Replacing chars is a poor solution.

I replaced encodeURIComponent for escape and works fine, but escape is deprecated since ECMAScript v3.

This issue occurs because encodeURIComponent works with UTF-8 and Excel does not.

Better way for me.

Encode data to base64 and export like this. I used jquery-base64 plugin from https://github.com/carlo/jquery-base64/blob/master/jquery.base64.min.js

And change code to:

```
window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,' + $.base64.encode(html));
```

If you don't want to use jquery, you can use this base64_encode function
http://phpjs.org/functions/base64_encode

"Base64 encoding/decoding is already a native function in modern(tm) browsers: btoa(str) and atob(str) are the functions that should can be used without any external reimplementation." - chipairon

Comment: Its a good idea, if you could add a direct EncodetoBase64() function to your response for the people that dont want to use extra plugins like jquery i will grant the response to you

Comment: Base64 encoding/decoding is already a native function in modern(tm) browsers: `btoa(str)` and `atob(str)` are the functions that should can be used without any external reimplementation.
Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Base64_encoding_and_decoding

Comment: I set your answer as the correct one as promised, but if you could add the native function option contributed by @chipairon to the answer for other people to see it would be great ^^

Comment: And how do you name your file?

Answer (score 4):

Solved adding a replace for the problematic symbols:

```
function generateexcel(tableid) {
  var table= document.getElementById(tableid);
  var html = table.outerHTML;

  //add more symbols if needed...
  while (html.indexOf('á') != -1) html = html.replace('á', '&aacute;');
  while (html.indexOf('é') != -1) html = html.replace('é', '&eacute;');
  while (html.indexOf('í') != -1) html = html.replace('í', '&iacute;');
  while (html.indexOf('ó') != -1) html = html.replace('ó', '&oacute;');
  while (html.indexOf('ú') != -1) html = html.replace('ú', '&uacute;');
  while (html.indexOf('º') != -1) html = html.replace('º', '&ordm;');

  window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(html));
}
```

Comment: Simpler (prob. faster too): `html = html.replace(/á/g, '$aacute;');` etc. - the "g" after the regex makes it perform the substitution throughout the string, so you don't need the `while` loop.

Comment: @Pointy It works but the replace would be html = html.replace(/á/g, '&aacute;'); not $, if you put it as an answer i will accept it

Comment: I think it is a poor solution, we have so much symbols to replace all. I replaced encodeURIComponent for escape and works fine.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue, just replace encodeURIComponent for escape.

```
function generateexcel(tableid) {
 var table= document.getElementById(tableid);
 var html = table.outerHTML;
 window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + escape(html));
}
```

It works for me...

Comment: As Pedro Muniz said, `escape` is being deprecated. It is preferable to use base64 encoding.

Answer (score 2):

Just replace `encodeURIComponent` with `escape`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I use generateexcel function previously posted, just adding Capital letters of special characters in order to make it work

```
    function generateexcel(tableid) {
      var table= document.getElementById(tableid);
      var html = table.outerHTML;
      while (html.indexOf('á') != -1) html = html.replace('á', '&aacute;');
      while (html.indexOf('Á') != -1) html = html.replace('Á', '&Aacute;');
      while (html.indexOf('é') != -1) html = html.replace('é', '&eacute;');
      while (html.indexOf('É') != -1) html = html.replace('É', '&Eacute;');
      while (html.indexOf('í') != -1) html = html.replace('í', '&iacute;');
      while (html.indexOf('Í') != -1) html = html.replace('Í', '&Iacute;');
      while (html.indexOf('ó') != -1) html = html.replace('ó', '&oacute;');
      while (html.indexOf('Ó') != -1) html = html.replace('Ó', '&Oacute;');
      while (html.indexOf('ú') != -1) html = html.replace('ú', '&uacute;');
      while (html.indexOf('Ú') != -1) html = html.replace('Ú', '&Uacute;');
      while (html.indexOf('º') != -1) html = html.replace('º', '&ordm;');
      while (html.indexOf('ñ') != -1) html = html.replace('ñ', '&ntilde;'); 
      while (html.indexOf('Ñ') != -1) html = html.replace('Ñ', '&Ntilde;');  

  window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(html));
}
```

Hope it helps...