# How to correct special chars when exporting html table to Excel

Tags: javascript, html, character-encoding, export-to-excel

I have only a HTML page and need to export a table as Excel document. There is no back-end. Must achieve this only with Javascript.

I am doing export process with this line of js;

```
window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent($('#excelContainer').html()));
```

And HTML page has this meta tag;

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

But my table contains some Turkish special chars and Excel doesn't show them correctly.

I've done a research but all solutions works from back-end so need a little help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Encoding data to base64 and export like this. This jquery plugin may help you
 https://github.com/carlo/jquery-base64/blob/master/jquery.base64.min.js

and you can change the code to `window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,' + $.base64.encode(html);`

Since am not into this field i got this answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11084564/export-html-table-to-excel-javascript-function-special-characters-changed).

Hope it helps

Comment: Tried it. Returns "Error: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: DOM Exception 5"

Comment: Update: Instead of jQuery plugin I used the Javascript function from [here](http://phpjs.org/functions/base64_encode/) and changed my code like this;

    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,' + base64_encode($('#excelContainer').html()));

Special chars still rendering wrong. But wrong chars were rendering like "ÄŸ". And now they like "_1".

Answer (score 0):

JQuery Base64 works for me too. Once a time jquery.base64.min.js is imported on page, command below works fine.

```
window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,' + jQuery.base64.encode(jQuery('#dvTableData').html()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use that
`<meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8\">`
in head tag.