# Knockout - Export html table with formatting

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, export-to-excel

How can I export a table generated using Knockout that will maintain the formatting?

I was using this solution ([How to export html table to excel using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566831/how-to-export-html-table-to-excel-using-javascript)), but it does not include formatting.

Comment: What formatting? What do you mean by that?

Comment: CSS formatting, I guess I need a way to convert the computed style to inline.

Comment: This doens't really have anything to do with knockout. You are looking for a way to export html with styling (I don't think this is possible). That the html was generated by knockout is irrelevant.

Comment: i know it's not strictly Knockout related, but i though it might help to include the library used to generate the HTML. I guess I could have included jQuery too. I almost have a solution now using [this inline css plugin](https://github.com/mvhenten/jQuery-inline-css).

Comment: Try http://excelbuilderjs.com/ (yeah, I built it). If you need a hand with it I can assist. We're using it at the company I work for with some pretty outstanding results.

Comment: @Stephen I'll check it out. Why not submit it as an answer?

Comment: Well, it's likely not 100% what you're looking for as it requires a bit of extra instructions to get things the way you want. But, I'll submit an answer anyway with a bit more info..

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment, [excelbuilderjs.com](http://excelbuilderjs.com) might work out for you. There are a couple of distinct downsides - one in that you can't simply turn an HTML table into an excel spreadsheet with colors and etc. It does require setup. But, in the case of where I work, we have a fairly standard color scheme and set of formatters that has been translated into a standalone set of instructions that is then included everywhere we need to construct a spreadsheet.

Based on a few simple examples of Knockout, you could probably just use the same data source to loop through and assign to EB - then just assign number formatting and date formatting as you would for an actual excel spreadsheet (i.e. $#,##0.00 for basic currency, m/d/yyyy for a basic date).

Side note - apparently some of my documentation didn't make it up. 
http://excelbuilderjs.com/cookbook/formatting.html is where you can get some basic info on formatting.