# Manipulate HTML Table in Browser

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, web, firefox-addon

I do a lot of reading of charts and graphs, and I was wondering if there was a FF or GC extension that allows me to do things like swap rows and columns in a drag and drop type fashion.

For example, if I want to compare the values in Rows 1, 55, 92 and 143, is there a way I can rearrange the table to put those four rows at the top of the chart for easy comparison?

I know I could probably copy and paste it into Excel, I was hoping that there was a solution with the browser.

Comment: You can use the chrome inspector to move elements around. Or you could write a bookmarklet to add the functionality

Comment: did the updated javascript only/non jQuery version of the answer solve the problem for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/tabletools2/

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/export-to-csv/

You can also export to excel:

[How to export html table to excel using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566831/how-to-export-html-table-to-excel-using-javascript)

http://www.mrkent.com/tools/converter/

I however... highlight what I need > cntrl c > cntrl v into excel and done.

Comment: Yeah, I know I can do it in Excel but I do it so often it would be easier if I could do it in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
var rowIndexWanted = [4, 5];

var table1 = document.getElementById('table1');
var table1body = table1.getElementsByTagName('tbody');
var rows = table1.getElementsByTagName('tr');
var rowsWanted = [];

for(i in rowIndexWanted)
{
    rowsWanted.push(rows[rowIndexWanted[i]]);
}

for(i in rowsWanted)
{
    table1body[0].insertBefore(rowsWanted[i], table1body[0].childNodes[0]);
}
```

Comment: No, it is a bunch of numbers and statistics I view on a site generated by someone else.

Comment: try the above javascript snippet. assuming the page is using jQuery, you can just pull up firebug or chrome debugger, and run the code

Comment: I tried the code and got this message                       TypeError: $(...) is null
[Break On This Error]  

$("#table1 tr")

Comment: the code snippet only works if the page is already using jQuery. try typing `jQuery` or `$` in the console, and see if you get `ReferenceError`, or `function()`. And obviously you need to replace #table1 with the id of the table. if the table doesn't have an id, you can add one to it using firebug or chrome debugger

Comment: I ran it and got `function()`

Comment: did you replace `table1` with the actual id of the table?

Comment: the table doesn't have a name

Comment: you can add an id to the table by right clicking on the table and Inspect Element in FireBug, find the `<table>` tag, right click it, and edit html, and add an `id='MyTable'` to the `<table>` tag

Comment: I gave the table the ID of "table1" because that's how you had it in your original code. I got the error `ypeError: $(...).filter is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

.filter(function(index){`

Comment: lol,, maybe the page doesn't have jQuery after all. try the pure javascript version above

Comment: You can [jQuerify](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/04/better-stronger-safer-jquerify-bookmarklet) a page

Answer (score 0):

**Tip:** you can select cells (in Firefox at least) by maintaining the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key pressed and selecting range of cells.

[Bookmarklets from J. Ruderman](https://www.squarefree.com/bookmarklets/pagedata.html) let you sort a table by any column, transpose it or number the rows.

What you're searching seems similar to functionalities offered by frameworks like Kendo: [column reordering](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/column-reordering.html) or [Aggregates](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/aggregates.html)?