# Jquery FullCalendar export to excel

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, fullcalendar

I am using Jquery **Full Calendar**.

I want to export **table** to **excel** in **Full Calendar**.

I **tried** below

```
 var calendar = $('#calendar').attr("name");

 alert(calendar);

 window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + x);
 e.preventDefault();
```

However this **did not work for me**.I only get data with above javascript code and not **all** (data,css,classes,html etc.)

On http://fullcalendar.io/wiki/Support/ it says  post your question on the StackOverflow fullcalendar tag.

That is why i ask question here.

I hope anybody can help me thanks.

Comment: Need your error message and your running enviroment

Comment: thanks for reply i do not get any error.Problem about Full Calander.http://fullcalendar.io/ in this page if you can export web page(Calendar table) to excel , my problem will be solved.If i run javascript code(in my question) i only get text not everything.I want to get everything in calander(table,text,data,css,etc)

Answer (score 0):

I know you can export and HTML to Excel so i found this script for another question where you can generate it easily with jQuery:

[How to export html table to excel using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566831/how-to-export-html-table-to-excel-using-javascript)

Just get the table element with jQuery and use this script on it.

Hope it helps!