# The file format and extension of 'file.xls' don't match with fileSaver.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, excel, blob, filesaver.js

I want to save a html table in a excel file, I used fileSaver for angular. But when I download the file and try to open it I receive an annoying popup from excel which say

"The file format and extension of 'report.xls' don't match. The file could be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its source, don't open it. Do you want to open it anyway?"

```
$scope.exportExcel = function(){

    var data, table;
    table = document.getElementById('tableReport').innerHTML;
    data = new Blob([table], {
        type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=charset=utf-8'
    });
    return FileSaver.saveAs(data, 'report.xls');
};
```

How can I fix this popup? Thanks.

Comment: The proper extension for that format  is .htm not .xls

Comment: @musa: thx for your answer but I want to extract it in excel not html

Comment: It is html, and excel expects a .htm extension for that type of file. Specifying an extension is not going to convert data from one format to another

Comment: I found this answer very helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/50819212/414744

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue.

I figured that I forgot to set the `responseType` to `blob` on my HTTP request.
This seems to be required in order to read binary data correctly.

Example:

```
$http({
    url: 'your/webservice',
    method: "POST",
    data: json, //this is your json data string
    headers: {
       'Content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    responseType: 'blob'
}).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    var blob = new Blob([data], {type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"});
    var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.open(objectUrl);
}).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    //upload failed
});
```

The code comes from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22448640/1132522).