# Remove Styles from Text when Copying / Cutting using CSS or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, copy, cut

Yo,

Alright been noodling on this one for a while: **How copy/cut styled text without bringing along any style baggage (background-color, color, etc)?**

Couple of routes of attacks that have been foiled:

1. **Style the text differently using ::select?** *Doesn't work, ::style isn't copied*
2. **Style the selected text using jQuery's select binding** *This only works for inputs, not p, divs*
3. **Intercept and remove style by binding an event to copy/paste using jQuery?** *Can't access the copied object to remove stuff, tried using e.preventDefault(); then returning the event object but that didn't work either*
4. **Modify the clipboard data once it's been saved?** *Also no dice, most browsers wont let you into this without flash and some sort confirmation*

Anyway, thoughts? Seems like it would be very useful for sites that have white background colors.

Comment: Just to be sure I understand, you want to copy plain text to the clipboard with no formatting?

Comment: Yup. I'd like to prevent the default copy / cut from grabbing styles. Or even awesomer do selectively, say leave font-family and font-weight but nix color and background. If I had to guess how to do this, you'd

Comment: Change the text before it's copied. Once things are delivered to the clipboard they seem to be inaccessible via javascript.

Comment: As a potential workaround for some cases, putting the text that is to be copied into an input or textarea might work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't got time to code up an example now, but you could do this for cut/copy triggered by keyboard shortcuts. It wouldn't work for cut/copy via context menu or Edit menu options because it relies on changing the user selection before the cut or copy event fires.

The steps:

1. Handle the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd> keyboard shortcuts and the Mac equivalents.
2. In this handler, create an off-screen element (absolute position and left -10000px, say) and copy the selected content into it. You can do this using `window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).cloneContents()`, although you'll need separate code for IE < 9 and you should check the selection is not collapsed.
3. Do whatever you like to to change the styling of the content of the off-screen element.
4. Move the selection to encompass the content of the off-screen element so that it is this content that is cut or copied.
5. Add a brief delay (a few milliseconds) using to `window.setTimeout()` that calls a function that removes the offscreen element and restores the original selection.

Comment: Working through this somewhat, any hints on how to move the selection?

Comment: @Mojowen: Here's an example function for selecting the contents of an element: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044616/select-a-complete-table-with-javascript-to-be-copied-to-clipboard/2044793#2044793

Comment: I think I've got it, thanks Tim. With some cleanup, looks a lot like this: http://jsfiddle.net/mojowen/hCHWy/

Comment: Thanks @Mojowen. One tweak, I had to add a `sel.removeAllRanges();` above `sel.addRange(now);` in the `fix` function.

Answer (score 12):

Given current browser capabilities, you can intercept the copy event, get the selection without style, and put that into the clipboard.

I've tested this code with Chrome/Safari/Firefox.  Believe is should work on MS browsers as well.

```
document.addEventListener('copy', function(e) {
  const text_only = document.getSelection().toString();
  const clipdata = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;  
  clipdata.setData('text/plain', text_only);
  clipdata.setData('text/html', text_only);
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need this to occur in the browser... for each user?

If **not** - and it is just for you - then you can do this with Clipmate software.

http://www.clipmate.com/index.htm

It has a feature that removes all styling.

Comment: I was looking for this to happen on any copy / cut, not just something specific.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have triggered the copy or cut you can strip the html tags and only the text with some regex

```
var String = Sample.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
```

Also if you have your stored text in a div with id "sample_div" 
Use `var String=$('sample_div').text('');` to get only the text inside

Comment: So how would I use this in the context a copy/cut event? I'ved tried it with:

`jQuery(document).bind('cut copy', function(e) { 
var String = Sample.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,""); 
return string; 
});` 

Sample isn't recognized