# *Really* change text color on select

Tags: html, css, copy, selection

We have a link that is often copied to the users email tool, including color and background color. Since there is a Whitelabel solution, this can cause a problem when the text is white.

1. text is white
2. user selects the text to copy it
3. text is white again (and in the worst case, the background color is lost)

I know the ::selection pseudo class, but it doesn't help for the copy process. See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vvfL2516/

```
.background { background: #222; }

.link { color: #fff; }
.link::-moz-selection {
    background: #f00;
    color: #0f0;
}
.link::selection {
    background: #f00;
    color: #0f0;
}
```

---

Thunderbird shows a blue link (=nice), but it's invisible in Libre Office and Google Docs, ... (not nice)

**Update 2015-09-24:**

The link form Andrew Lyndem contains the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7454048/461754

Comment: Maybe something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439210/remove-styles-from-text-when-copying-cutting-using-css-or-javascript

Comment: use :active or :focus

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/vvfL2516/1/

Comment: I copy-pasted your version on a WordPress WYSIWYG editor just now and it works beautifully. Don't know how it looks on the email tools though.

Comment: @AndrewLyndem well colours can be adjusted to taste!! :)

Comment: I've worked with the base from @Andrew Lyndem Comment. This seems to be the only solution!

Answer (score 0):

if you really really want to change it, use not only active and focus a attributes, but also an a:hover so that it highlights when you hover over it

```css
.background {
  background: #222;
}
.link {
  color: #fff;
}
.link::-moz-selection {
  background: #f00;
  color: #0f0;
}
.link::selection {
  background: #f00;
  color: #0f0;
}
a:focus,
a:hover,
a:active {
  background: red;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <a class="link" href="https://app.tomvote.com/result/3a13bac6a6f93fa4fff0036bb1e8b7b5">Show Vote Results</a>
</div>
```

Comment: you can adjust the colors obviously, i have used bright ones to hughlight the effect :)

Comment: But will this work on email tools like Libre Office and Google Docs though? +1

Comment: have never used Libre Office. it would work on Google Docs though

Comment: I've tried this on Google Docs and Libre Office, but it does not work for me :( I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with Chrome.