# How to select DOM node in javascript in IE8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

Does anyone know how to select node (element) in IE8 in javascript?
Not using third-party libs is preferred.

In IE9 you can do like this:

```
var sel = window.getSelection();
sel.removeAllRanges();
var range = document.createRange();
range.selectNode(node);
sel.addRange(range);
```

How you can do this in IE8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For older IE it's this, provided `node` is an element:

```
var range = document.body.createTextRange();
range.moveToElementText(node);
range.select();
```

For a full cross-browser solution, see

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2044793/96100

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code I use, it should work across the board:

```
    var sel, range;
    if(window.getSelection && document.createRange) {
        range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(node);
        sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);

    } else if(document.body.createTextRange) {
        range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(node);
        range.select();
    }
```