# Select a paragraph with JavaScript (on click)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, textselection

Is it possible to select all the text of an element (e.g., a paragraph `<p>`) with JavaScript? A lot of people think jQuery `.select()` would do this, but it does not. It merely triggers an event. Note that DOM objects for `<input>` elements have a native `select()` method, but most other elements (such as `<output>` and `<p>`) do not.

(Do I need to use `content-editable` to get this to work?)

Comment: Select it how? Select the content with `.html()` or `.text()`, or highlight the text as if you did with your mouse by dragging?

Comment: @j08691 Probably highlighting since the OP talked about selecting the contents of a an `<input />`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2044793/96100, http://stackoverflow.com/a/2838358/96100

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use [Range.selectNodeContents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/selectNodeContents)

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(){
    var range = document.createRange();
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    range.selectNodeContents(document.querySelector('p'));
    
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
});
```

```html
Hello <p>Select me</p> World
<button id ='btn'>Select text</button>
```

Related links:

- The spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range/ranges.html#Level2-Range-method-selectNodeContents
- http://help.dottoro.com/ljcpcpnt.php
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/range.selectNodeContents
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection.addRange

For support across all browsers, see https://github.com/timdown/rangy from https://stackoverflow.com/users/96100/tim-down

Comment: awesome, fantastic that this does not require `contenteditable`. Also, major props for including a code snippet, spec references, working fiddle, links to more info! A+++ answer

Answer (score 3):

`select()` Will only work on `<input>` and `<textarea>` elements...

Also yes, you will have to use:

```
contenteditable="true"
```

And use `.focus()` to select all the text.

Try this:

```
<p id="editable" contenteditable="true" 
onfocus="document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null);">Your Text Here</p>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('editable').focus();" >Click me</button>
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r83973tu/1/)**

Comment: This doesn't select the text for me on Chrome. See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25456308/227299

Comment: Your jsFiddle only worked for me when the editable paragraph was already focused, which gave me the idea to use a window.setTimeout to allow the focus command to finish first. Success. Here's my fork of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/alanhogan/nfqx0ex2/