# copy whole html table to clipboard javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have write javascript to select the table but I want to now automaticaly copy it after the click of the button.Please help me.My javascript is like this.

```
function selectElementContents(el) {
            var body = document.body, range, sel;
            if (document.createRange && window.getSelection) {
                range = document.createRange();
                sel = window.getSelection();
                sel.removeAllRanges();
                try {
                    range.selectNodeContents(el);
                    sel.addRange(range);
                    document.execCommand('Copy');
                } catch (e) {
                    range.selectNode(el);
                    sel.addRange(range);
                    document.execCommand('Copy');
                }
            } else if (body.createTextRange) {
                range = body.createTextRange();
                range.moveToElementText(el);
                range.select();
                range.execCommand('Copy');

            }
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Comment: Credit: The code here and in one of the answers appears to have been taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2044793/943435 by @TimDown.  See the original for his working example.

Comment: In IE: `window.clipboardData.setData("text", el.outerHTML);`

Answer (score 23):

```
function selectElementContents(el) {
var body = document.body, range, sel;
if (document.createRange && window.getSelection) {
    range = document.createRange();
    sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    try {
        range.selectNodeContents(el);
        sel.addRange(range);
    } catch (e) {
        range.selectNode(el);
        sel.addRange(range);
    }
} else if (body.createTextRange) {
    range = body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(el);
    range.select();
}
document.execCommand("Copy");}
```

Comment: Note that [document.createRange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createRange) and [window.getSelection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection) are supported in all modern browsers, and even IE9+. Most web applications probably do not need the fallback anymore.

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function copytable(el) {
    var urlField = document.getElementById(el)   
    var range = document.createRange()
    range.selectNode(urlField)
    window.getSelection().addRange(range) 
    document.execCommand('copy')
}

</script>

<input type=button value="Copy to Clipboard" onClick="copytable('stats')">

<table id=stats>
    <tr>
        <td>hello</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 11):

I know this is an old one, but if any one still looking for a solution. this one worked for me

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#copyBtn").on("click",
            function(e) {
                copyTable("listTable", e);
            });

    });

    function copyTable(el, e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var table = document.getElementById(el);
        
        if (navigator.clipboard) {
            var text = table.innerText.trim();
            navigator.clipboard.writeText(text).catch(function () { });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Nice and easy, and still very useful, Thank you. Although `table.outerHTML` would be more appropriate, if one needed the table structure, for example to copy the table to Excel.

Comment: Additionally, if you don't want certain columns, you can hide them before you call `copyTable` and then unhide them afterward, perhaps with something like this: `$('#listTable td:nth-of-type(4)').css('display', 'none');` first, then call `copyTable`, then follow it all up with a `.css('display','');`

Answer (score 6):

- This has worked for me, it is not only restricted to table, but it can even select and copy to clipboard all elements inside Node specified with id.
- I have tested in Mac Chrome as well as windows chrome.
- Usescase : Copy Signature created by Signature Generator based on JS

Demo :

```html
<div id="signature_container">
  <p id="company_name" style="margin-top: 4px; margin-bottom: 0px; color: #522e64; font-weight: 700; font-size: 16px; letter-spacing: 1px; border-bottom: solid 2px #522e64; width:250px; padding-bottom: 3px;">The Company Name</p>
  <p style="margin-top: 4px; margin-bottom: 0px; color: #00706a; font-weight: 700; font-size: 15px;"> <span id="first_name_output_2"></span>Firstname<span id="last_name_output_2"> Lastname</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="designation_output_2" style="color: #000000; font-weight: 500; font-size: 15px;">Designation</span></p>
  <p style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; color: #625469; font-weight: normal; font-size: 15px; letter-spacing: 0.6px;">youreamil@xyz.com<span id="email_output_2"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
</div>
<br><br>
<input type="button" onclick="selectElementContents( document.getElementById('signature_container') );" value="Copy to Clipboard">

<script>
  function selectElementContents(el) {
    var body = document.body,
      range, sel;
    if (document.createRange && window.getSelection) {
      range = document.createRange();
      sel = window.getSelection();
      sel.removeAllRanges();
      range.selectNodeContents(el);
      sel.addRange(range);
    }
    document.execCommand("Copy");
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

## UPDATE

Use this code instead.

**Code:**

```js
function selectElementContents(el) {
    var body = document.body, range, sel;
    if (document.createRange && window.getSelection) {
        range = document.createRange();
        sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        try {
            range.selectNodeContents(el);
            sel.addRange(range);
        } catch (e) {
            range.selectNode(el);
            sel.addRange(range);
        }
    } else if (body.createTextRange) {
        range = body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(el);
        range.select();
        document.execCommand("copy");
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="select table"
  onclick="selectElementContents( document.getElementById('table') );">
  
<table id="table">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Heading</th><th>Heading</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>cell</td><td>cell</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: How to use that plugin?

Comment: Is there not any solution without using plugin?

Comment: This code just selects the whole table but it doesnot copy it.

Comment: @vitorio : I have tried to copy the hidden table. Do you have any idea about hidden table

Comment: Note that [document.createRange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createRange) and [window.getSelection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection) are supported in all modern browsers, and even IE9+. Most web applications probably do not need the fallback anymore.

Comment: @RKS just duplicate the `document.execCommand("copy");` line that's in the `else if` condition block into the bottom of the `if` condition block.

Answer (score 1):

The previous scripts did not work for me because the .execCommand("Copy") was not triggering. By attaching it to the document itself, and moving it outside of the conditional, I was able to get it to work:

I think this function is more robust:

```
  function selectElementContents(el) {
    var body = document.body, range, sel;
    if (document.createRange && window.getSelection) {
        range = document.createRange();
        sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        try {
            range.selectNodeContents(el);
            sel.addRange(range);
        } catch (e) {
            range.selectNode(el);
            sel.addRange(range);
        }
    } else if (body.createTextRange) {
        range = body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(el);
        range.select();
    }
    document.execCommand("Copy");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

by using a library called `clipboard.js` making it much easier.
for more info, check: https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/copy-to-clipboard-made-easy-with-clipboardjs--cms-25086

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/1.4.0/clipboard.min.js">
(function(){
    new Clipboard('#copy-table-button');
})();
</script>

<button class="btn" id="copy-table-button" data-clipboard-target="#table_results">Copy</button>
               

<table id='table_results' >

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this custom script, if you need to copy to clipboard all data from table;
html:

```
<button class='btnclipboard' data-source='tableStudents'> Copy table </button>

<table id="tableStudents">
<thead>
 <th> user_id </th>
 <th> Name </th> 
</thead> 
<tbody>
 <tr>
  <td> 123 </td>
  <td> Proba </td>
 </tr>
<tbody>
</table>

<script>
    $('.btnclipboard').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
        copyTableToClipboard($(this).data('source'));
});

function copyTableToClipboard() {


var clipboard=new Clipboard('.btnclipboard',{

    text: function(trigger) {

        var txt=[];
                var headColumns = [];
                $("#tableStudents th").each(function(){
                    var textColumn = $(this).text();
                    if(textColumn == null || textColumn == "") {
                        textColumn = $(this).attr('title');
                    }
                    if(textColumn == undefined || textColumn == null) {
                        textColumn = "";
                    }
                    headColumns.push(textColumn);
                    // console.log($(this).text());
                });
                console.log('headColumns', headColumns);
                var head=headColumns;
                txt.push(head.join("\t"));

                var rowColumns=[];
                $("#tableStudents tr").each(function(){
                    var row=[];
                    $(this).find('td').each(function(){
                        var textColumn = $(this).text();
                        if($(this).find("i").hasClass('fa-check')){
                            textColumn = "1";
                        }
                        // if(textColumn == "") {
                        //  // textColumn = $(this).attr('title');
                        //  textColumn = "";
                        // }
                        // if(textColumn != null) {
                            row.push(textColumn);
                        // }
                    //console.log($(this).text());
                    });
                    if(row.length > 0) {
                        rowColumns.push(row);
                        txt.push(row.join("\t"));
                    }
                });
                console.log('rowColumns', rowColumns);
                return txt.join("\n");
    }


});

clipboard.on('success', function(e) {

    console.info('Action:', e.action);
    e.clearSelection();

    if (Notification.permission == "granted")
    {
        var notification = new Notification('Data copied to clipboard', {
            icon: '../dist/img/favicon.png',
            body: "You can now paste (Ctrl+v) into your favorite spreadsheet editor !"
        });
    }else{
        console.warn(Notification.permission);
    }
});

clipboard.on('error', function(e) {
    console.error('Action:', e.action);
    console.error('Trigger:', e.trigger);
});
}
</script>
```

After you click on the button, your table data should be copied.

Answer (score -1):

```
function selectElementContents(el) {
var body = document.body, range, sel;
if (document.createRange && window.getSelection) {
    range = document.createRange();
    sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    try {
        range.selectNodeContents(el);
        sel.addRange(range);
    } catch (e) {
        range.selectNode(el);
        sel.addRange(range);
    }
} else if (body.createTextRange) {
    range = body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(el);
    range.select();





}
CopiedTxt = document.selection.createRange();
CopiedTxt.execCommand("Copy");}
```