# How to add a row of text above the output table when using write.table to copy and paste a data frame?

Tags: r, write.table

Suppose we have the following data frame called `data`, produced by the code immediately beneath:

```
> data
  ID Period Values
1  1      1      5
2  1      2     10
3  1      3     15
4  2      1     12
5  2      2      0
6  2      3      2
7  3      1      4
8  3      2     -8
9  3      3      3

data <- 
  data.frame(
    ID = (c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)),
    Period = as.numeric(c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)),
    Values = as.numeric(c(5, 10, 15, 12, 0, 2, 4, -8, 3))
  )
```

Next, we use the below simple code in base R to copy and paste `data` into an Excel sheet:

```
write.table(x = data,
            file = "clipboard",
            sep = "\t",
            row.names = FALSE,
            col.names = TRUE
  )
```

When copy/pasting data into Excel, I'd like a row of text describing the table inserted immediately above the table (such as: *Table name is "Data"*), as shown in the image below.

How can the above code be modified to insert a text row above the table? In base R preferably?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Clipboard alone

```r
writeLines(
  c("table name is mtcars",
    capture.output(write.table(mtcars[1:3,], sep = "\t", row.names = FALSE))),
  "clipboard")
```

... and then paste into Excel. I've run into issues in the past when the data has embedding issues (embedded tabs, etc) and perhaps something in the chain (including "me") did not handle all things correctly.

On windows, one could replace `writeLines(.., "clipboard")` with `writeClipboard`, but that function is windows only. On other OSes, one can install the `clipr` package for clipboard reading/writing.

### Using files

```r
writeLines("table name is mtcars", con = "somefile.csv")
write.table(mtcars[1:3,], "somefile.csv", row.names = FALSE, append = TRUE, sep = ",")
# Warning in write.table(mtcars[1:3, ], "somefile.csv", row.names = FALSE,  :
#   appending column names to file
```

(One cannot use `write.csv`, since it does not tolerate `append=TRUE`, complaining `attempt to set 'append' ignored`.)

Resulting file:

```
table name is mtcars
"mpg","cyl","disp","hp","drat","wt","qsec","vs","am","gear","carb"
21,6,160,110,3.9,2.62,16.46,0,1,4,4
21,6,160,110,3.9,2.875,17.02,0,1,4,4
22.8,4,108,93,3.85,2.32,18.61,1,1,4,1
```

It opens in Excel as

[image: excel snapshot]

Comment: Hi r2evans, your mtcars solution works fine, by saving the file as a csv, which you then open. What I am trying to do is a bit different: copy the dataframe + title row text to the "clipboard", and then paste it straight into the target spot in Excel by right-clicking the mouse. Try it with my OP code and you'll see that it works - except there is no title row text. I tried your solution for my "copy to clipboard" approach (con = "clipboard", write.table(x, file = "clipboard",...) and I get "Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :  'mode' for the clipboard must be 'r' or 'w'".

Comment: Sure, see my edit.