# Clipboard api is not working with table element

Tags: javascript, html

I have to copy HTML table element from HTML page to excel, I'm trying to implement this with clipboard API, but
in my case, clipboard API is working only with the Input element, but not with a table.
Can somebody help?

[`Plunker`](https://plnkr.co/edit/lGbGzDr1PumoOnMFLvBE?p=preview)

Comment: [Select a complete table with Javascript (to be copied to clipboard)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044616/select-a-complete-table-with-javascript-to-be-copied-to-clipboard).

Comment: -Alon Adler, Awesome, thank you!