# How to copy HTML to clipboard using react hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-ref

I have a section that has a table now I want the user to be able to copy the HTML code of the table to the clipboard.

Here is my solution on code sandbox : [live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/copy-html-to-clipboard-ouyri?file=/src/App.js)

Js code below

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const tableRef = useRef(null);
  const [copySuccess, setCopySuccess] = useState("");

  const copyToClipboard = (e) => {
    const code =tableRef.current.innerHTML;
    console.log('code', code);
    document.execCommand("copy");
    e.target.focus();
    setCopySuccess("Copied!");
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div ref={tableRef} className="table">
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>First Name</th>
              <th>Last Name</th>
              <th>Username</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>Mark</td>
              <td>Otto</td>
              <td>@mdo</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

      {document.queryCommandSupported("copy") && (
        <div>
          <button onClick={copyToClipboard}>Copy</button>
          {copySuccess}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Unfortunately, this is not copying the HTML code.**

What do I need to change to be able to copy HTML to the clipboard.?

What is wrong here?

Comment: You need to select the contents of the table. See this for a function to select a table's contents: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044616/select-a-complete-table-with-javascript-to-be-copied-to-clipboard (then pass it `tableRef.current`)

Comment: @PeterCollingridge check my live demo solution click copy u will see the console code return the table using tableRef.current.innerHTML; the  problem is how do I copy that to clip board

Comment: You can't use `document.execCommand("copy")` unless you select the content first. To write from a variable you will have to use `navigator.clipboard.writeText`. For details, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard

Comment: Do you want to copy the HTML text to the clipboard so that the user is going to paste the HTML "code" or do you want to copy the HTML elements so the user is going to paste the HTML table into let's say Word or some other application?

Comment: @KrisztiánBalla I want to copy the HTML code  by which user can paste eg into email as signature

Comment: @PeterCollingridge i get this error with that https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttecA.png ?

Comment: It's difficult to tell what that means. It could be an issue with the sandbox itself. Are you able to set up a simple react-app locally and test? I added `navigator.clipboard.writeText('...')` into a random react app I had running and it seemed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is it copies selected/highlighted text to the clipboard so you just need to do that programmatically before running execCommand.

1. Add a hidden input (set invisible and position absolute/off-screen)
2. In copy function, set the value of that input to the html
3. select the hidden input with the select event
4. execCommand(‘copy’);

EDIT

It might work with an input type of hidden or setting display: none; but I vaguely remember this blocking the select event when I did this a few years back.

Comment: please here is link to code sandbox can you show your solution via code ? https://codesandbox.io/s/copy-html-to-clipboard-ouyri?file=/src/App.js  u can just edit that code

Comment: @TheDeadMan I saved changes to your codesandbox project and added comments to help clarify the details

Comment: when u save the project it become forked so you need to share the new saved project so that I can see your canges thanks

Comment: @TheDeadMan Sorry about that! https://codesandbox.io/s/copy-html-to-clipboard-forked-4tmsh?file=/src/App.js