# Add client function to table

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-selectors

**EDIT**

[image]

```
 Table table = new Table();
 TableRow tableRow = new TableRow();
 TableCell tableCell = new TableCell();

 tableCell.Text = "id";
 tableRow.Cells.Add(tableCell);

 tableCell = new TableCell();
 tableCell.Text = "name";                        
 tableRow.Cells.Add(tableCell);

 table.Rows.Add(tableRow);
```

//-----------

```
 tableRow = new TableRow();
 tableCell = new TableCell();
 tableCell.Text = "1";
 tableRow.Cells.Add(tableCell);

 tableCell = new TableCell();
 tableCell.Text = "a";                        
 tableRow.Cells.Add(tableCell);

 table.Rows.Add(tableRow);
 tableRow = new TableRow();


 tableRow = new TableRow();
 tableCell = new TableCell();
 tableCell.Text = "2";
 tableRow.Cells.Add(tableCell);

 tableCell = new TableCell();
 tableCell.Text = "b";                        
 tableRow.Cells.Add(tableCell);

 table.Rows.Add(tableRow);
 tableRow = new TableRow();
```

How can add client function to the first row?

I want when the user clicks on the first row (name or id) `slideToggle` other row.

This table is created at run time.

Comment: seems duplicate to - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207939/adding-an-onclick-event-to-a-table-row

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding an onclick event to a table row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207939/adding-an-onclick-event-to-a-table-row)

Answer (score 0):

you give this row an id for example id="row1",

I am not sure how to give the table and the row an id in ASP,

```
$("#row1").live("click", function(){
    $(this).slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: change row1 to ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_row1 at run time