# Table colour change over mouse click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to change the particular html table  cell colour while the mouse click event occurs. Which one is most suit to my need whether CSS or Javascript?

Comment: Javascript/JQUERY click event is how I would do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jquery function that should do the trick

```
$(document).on('click', '#tableID', function(e){
         $(this).css('background','#000080');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is jquery function to change particular html table cell color when mouse click event occurs.

**CODE:**

```
$(document).on('click', '#TABLEID', function(e){
         $(e.target).css('background','#6688ff');
});
```

**DEMO:**

http://jsfiddle.net/Ra2VP/

Comment: Why don't you use `this` instead of `e.target`?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫: `this` refers to `table element` and color will be applied to whole table. But in question user clearly mentioned that color has to apply only to particular `html cell`. `e.target` will do same.

Comment: I thought `this` is referring to the table cell... by the way why don't you use `'#codexpl td'` then `this` will be the same as `e.target`.

Comment: No both are different. If we use `#codexpl td` then color will be applied for all td's in that table.

Comment: No it won't. It means the eventListener is applied to the cell. http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/Ra2VP/2/

Answer (score 0):

Refer this for creating click event on table row.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207939/adding-an-onclick-event-to-a-table-row
```

use css to set the color for the table or by,

```
mycurrent_row.style.backgroundColor = "#EEF4EA";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
$('td').click(function(){
    $(this).css('background-color','red');
    $('td').not($(this)).css('background-color','white');
});
```

See this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8pqJ7/)