# How to "input button" run php functions

Tags: php, html

Please help me to fix this code :(

```
echo'<td style=" width: 20%"><input type="button" value="inactive" onclick="set_user_inactive($user_id)">   
        </td>';
```

I need function **set_user_inactive($user_id)** works if user click on the button in the table.

I won't use form I need it v.simple

html and php

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207939/adding-an-onclick-event-to-a-table-row

Comment: Wait, is `set_user_inactive()` a php function? In this universe, you cannot run PHP from the client side. You'll need a lot more than a simple onclick call to run a PHP function, ajax is your best bet. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165395/call-php-function-from-javascript

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no you cant do this. Php is run on page load and cannot be interacted with via the dom.

A slightly longer answer would be to set up a service page to handle your php which you can run from the from end.

Create a single php call it something like setInactive.php and do something like the following

```
<?php
set_user_inactive($_POST["user_id"])
?>
```

Then use javascript or jquery to post to that page.

```
function set_user_inactive(val){
 $.post( "setInactive.php", { user_id: val} );
}
```

Thats a rough starting point hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Here you go , this will call JavaScript function

```
        $user_id    = 1; 

        $onclick    =   "onclick=set_user_inactive($user_id);";


        echo    '<td style=" width: 20%">

                   <input type="button" value="inactive" '."onclick=set_user_inactive($user_id)".'>   

                </td>';
```

Comment: You're not using $onclick after definition at all, what's the point?

Comment: @CodingAnt why $onclick ?

Comment: As per my understanding , set_user_function is a JavaScript function @Robuust .

Comment: $onclick separate beacause I m not able to save my answer here so only a workaround :P @NamshanNet