# how to add event handler on row of table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

```
var table = $("<table />").attr({id:'table1'});            
        var appenddata;
        names = Object.keys(res);
        var row = $('<tr />');
        $(names).each(function (index, value) {
            $(row).append("<th>" + value + "</th>");
        });
        $(table).append(row);
        $(Result).each(function (index, value) {
            var tr = $('<tr />').attr({});
            $(names).each(function (i,iValue) {
                $(tr).append("<td>" + value[names[i]]+"</td>");
            });
            $(table).append(tr);
        });

        $("#tab1").append(table);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YXQ6.jpg)

[image]
I have this table, I want to add click event on rows, like if user click on anywhere on the row, It shows an alert.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding an onclick event to a table row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207939/adding-an-onclick-event-to-a-table-row)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do with [`on()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiu9eiEpZzUAhXMO48KHVoRBQoQFggsMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fon%2F&usg=AFQjCNFJf1Y9q7iSptlkW-9S_Ki4f0hD8w&sig2=QzFyynd5hxCfVA8ys5rlvw) click for dynamically created element. Add the below code in your js

```
$(document).on('click','#table1 tr',function(){
alert('something')
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
// table is a refence to the HTMLTableElement
var trList = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
for(var index = 0; index < trList.length; index++) {
    trList[index].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        alert("Row Clicked");
    });
}
```

Here is a working example

```js
var table = document.getElementById("table");
var trList = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
for(var index = 0; index < trList.length; index++) {
    (function (index){
        trList[index].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
            alert("Row " + (index+1) + " Clicked");
        });
    }(index));
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Row 1
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Row 2
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not band a event to a future element!
You must user a other element to proxy the event for the future element!

```
$("body").on('click','#table1 tr',function(){
    alert('your msg');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
     $(function(){
         $(document).on('click','#table1 tr',function(e){
            alert(this.data('message'));
         })
      });


       // This will come inside your custom method or ajax success
        var table = $("<table />").attr({id:'table1'});            
        var appenddata;
        names = Object.keys(res);
        var row = $('<tr />');
        $(names).each(function (index, value) {
            $(row).append("<th>" + value + "</th>");
        });
        $(table).append(row);
        $(Result).each(function (index, value) {

            var tr = $('<tr />', { 'class': 'classname','data-message' :value[names[i]]});
            $(names).each(function (i,iValue) {
                $(tr).append("<td>" + value[names[i]]+"</td>");
            });
            $(table).append(tr);
        });

        $("#tab1").append(table);
```